# Анимация рисования и заполнения двойного контура SVG

Tags: css, svg, css-animation, svg-animation

Есть два замкнутых контура в SVG (выделенные красным цветом).

Как можно сделать плавную прорисовку этих объектов (выделенные красным цветом)? С автоматическим стартом начала прорисовки, и какие еще варианты есть управления?

```html
    <svg width="461" height="342" viewBox="0 0 461 342" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<g clip-path="url(#clip0)">
<path d="M261.34 150.95C261.34 192.89 227.34 226.9 185.39 226.9C143.44 226.9 109.44 192.9 109.44 150.95C109.45 109 143.45 75 185.4 75C227.34 75 261.34 109 261.34 150.95Z" fill="#F3EC18"/>
<path d="M459.2 341.82H1.55C0.69 341.82 0 341.12 0 340.27C0 339.41 0.7 338.72 1.55 338.72H459.2C460.06 338.72 460.75 339.42 460.75 340.27C460.76 341.12 460.06 341.82 459.2 341.82Z" fill="black"/>
</g>
<g clip-path="url(#clip1)">
<path d="M123.85 153.28C123.78 153.28 123.71 153.28 123.64 153.27C122.79 153.15 122.2 152.37 122.32 151.52L122.82 147.91C122.94 147.06 123.72 146.47 124.57 146.58C125.42 146.7 126.01 147.48 125.9 148.33L125.4 151.94C125.28 152.72 124.61 153.28 123.85 153.28Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M123.75 143.44C123.62 143.44 123.48 143.42 123.36 143.39L93.0396 135.41C92.4596 135.26 92.0196 134.78 91.9096 134.19L85.9296 101.62C85.7696 100.78 86.3296 99.97 87.1796 99.81C88.0296 99.66 88.8296 100.21 88.9896 101.06L94.7896 132.66L123.57 140.23L127.66 138.09C128.42 137.69 129.36 137.99 129.76 138.75C130.16 139.51 129.86 140.45 129.1 140.84L124.48 143.26C124.25 143.38 124 143.44 123.75 143.44Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M215.62 17.01C214.76 17.01 214.07 16.32 214.07 15.46V1.55C214.07 0.69 214.77 0 215.62 0C216.48 0 217.17 0.69 217.17 1.55V15.46C217.18 16.32 216.48 17.01 215.62 17.01Z" fill="#1A1A1A"/>
<path d="M164.41 38.6901C164.01 38.6901 163.62 38.5401 163.31 38.2401L154.88 29.8101C154.27 29.2001 154.27 28.2201 154.88 27.6201C155.49 27.0101 156.47 27.0101 157.07 27.6201L165.5 36.0501C166.11 36.6601 166.11 37.6401 165.5 38.2401C165.2 38.5401 164.81 38.6901 164.41 38.6901Z" fill="#1A1A1A"/>
<path d="M268.141 36.6901C267.741 36.6901 267.351 36.5401 267.041 36.2401C266.431 35.6301 266.431 34.6501 267.041 34.0501L275.171 25.9201C275.781 25.3201 276.761 25.3101 277.361 25.9201C277.971 26.5301 277.971 27.5101 277.361 28.1101L269.231 36.2401C268.931 36.5401 268.531 36.6901 268.141 36.6901Z" fill="#1A1A1A"/>
<path id="lamp1" d="M189.89 234.13C189.08 234.13 188.4 233.5 188.35 232.68C188.33 232.34 185.81 198.72 166 182.55C152.11 171.2 142.91 152.89 142 134.76C141.11 116.97 146.48 100.14 157.13 87.39C168.01 74.36 183.58 66.7 200.97 65.83C201.27 65.81 201.57 65.8 201.92 65.79L202.3 65.78C203.16 65.74 203.87 66.4 203.91 67.25L206.19 112.79C206.19 112.84 206.19 112.89 206.19 112.93C206.12 114.64 206.66 116.19 207.73 117.3C209.15 118.78 211.34 119.23 213.11 118.35C214.1 117.86 215.16 117.01 216.38 116.02C219.46 113.54 223.29 110.45 229.55 110.14C229.85 110.12 230.15 110.12 230.45 110.12C239.85 110.12 247.01 117.05 247.85 126.97C248.41 133.6 245.83 137.91 243.57 140.37C240.44 143.77 235.97 145.72 231.31 145.72C230.91 145.72 230.5 145.72 230.1 145.68C225.49 145.34 220.93 143.44 217.27 141.91C216.29 141.5 215.37 141.12 214.58 140.82C212.82 140.16 210.95 140.61 209.6 141.98C208.48 143.12 207.84 144.75 207.87 146.45L212.13 231.46C212.15 231.87 212.01 232.27 211.73 232.58C211.45 232.88 211.07 233.07 210.66 233.09L189.98 234.13C189.95 234.13 189.92 234.13 189.89 234.13ZM200.89 68.9401C167.29 70.7501 143.32 98.94 145.1 134.61C145.97 151.89 154.72 169.34 167.96 180.15C186.58 195.36 190.59 223.97 191.31 230.95L208.96 230.07L204.78 146.56C204.74 143.98 205.69 141.54 207.4 139.81C209.6 137.58 212.78 136.84 215.68 137.93C216.52 138.25 217.48 138.64 218.48 139.06C221.94 140.5 226.24 142.3 230.35 142.61C230.68 142.63 231 142.65 231.33 142.65C235.12 142.65 238.76 141.06 241.3 138.3C243.14 136.3 245.24 132.75 244.77 127.25C244.07 119 238.19 113.24 230.47 113.24C230.22 113.24 229.97 113.25 229.72 113.26C224.46 113.52 221.21 116.15 218.34 118.46C217.03 119.52 215.79 120.52 214.49 121.16C213.44 121.68 212.32 121.94 211.16 121.94C209.06 121.94 206.99 121.04 205.49 119.47C203.85 117.76 203 115.43 203.09 112.9L200.89 68.9401Z" fill="red"/>
<path d="M193.64 247.17C192.82 247.17 192.13 246.53 192.09 245.7C192.05 244.84 192.71 244.12 193.56 244.07L212 243.15C212.84 243.12 213.59 243.77 213.63 244.62C213.67 245.48 213.01 246.2 212.16 246.25L193.71 247.17C193.7 247.16 193.67 247.17 193.64 247.17Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M201.06 260.79C200.24 260.79 199.55 260.15 199.51 259.32C199.47 258.46 200.13 257.73 200.98 257.69L212.19 257.13C213.04 257.09 213.77 257.75 213.81 258.6C213.85 259.46 213.19 260.18 212.34 260.23L201.13 260.79C201.11 260.79 201.09 260.79 201.06 260.79Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M106.82 186.06C106.02 186.06 105.34 185.29 105.28 184.49L104.54 175.32C104.47 174.46 105.11 173.68 105.96 173.61C106.83 173.54 107.56 174.16 107.63 175.01L108.25 182.6C112.62 182.35 125.63 181.31 132.81 177.47C131.19 173.09 129.87 166.75 129.81 166.46C129.64 165.62 130.17 164.8 131.01 164.63C131.84 164.45 132.67 164.99 132.84 165.83C132.86 165.91 134.45 173.53 136.17 177.53C136.47 178.23 136.22 179.19 135.58 179.6C126.64 185.28 107.68 186.06 106.87 186.06C106.85 186.06 106.84 186.06 106.82 186.06Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M101.35 185.96C90.2696 185.96 75.4196 182.43 74.7996 182.28C74.0496 182.1 73.5396 181.39 73.6196 180.62C73.6996 179.86 75.4596 161.89 76.4596 155.6C76.5896 154.75 77.3996 154.18 78.2296 154.31C79.0796 154.44 79.6496 155.24 79.5196 156.08C78.6996 161.29 77.2796 175.15 76.8396 179.56C80.7396 180.42 92.4996 182.85 101.35 182.85C102.21 182.85 102.9 183.55 102.9 184.4C102.9 185.26 102.2 185.96 101.35 185.96Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M120.93 328.14C120.16 328.14 119.49 327.56 119.39 326.77C118.54 319.71 117.56 313.73 116.43 306.81C113.65 289.8 109.85 266.5 104.53 206.05C104.45 205.2 105.09 204.44 105.94 204.37C106.8 204.29 107.55 204.93 107.62 205.78C112.92 266.12 116.72 289.35 119.49 306.32C120.62 313.28 121.61 319.28 122.47 326.41C122.57 327.26 121.97 328.03 121.12 328.14C121.05 328.14 120.99 328.14 120.93 328.14Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M73.83 327.86C73.01 327.86 72.32 327.21 72.28 326.38C71.89 318.52 71.73 309.06 71.53 297.08C71.39 288.56 71.23 278.91 70.95 268.01C70.83 263.39 70.67 259.01 70.51 254.77C69.74 233.88 69.07 215.83 74.65 188.98C74.82 188.14 75.65 187.6 76.48 187.78C77.32 187.95 77.86 188.78 77.68 189.61C72.18 216.09 72.84 233.96 73.61 254.66C73.77 258.9 73.93 263.29 74.05 267.93C74.33 278.84 74.49 288.51 74.64 297.03C74.84 308.98 75 318.41 75.38 326.23C75.42 327.09 74.76 327.81 73.91 327.86C73.88 327.85 73.85 327.86 73.83 327.86Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M139.26 341.13C137.61 341.13 135.42 339.94 131.39 337.74C130.78 337.41 130.14 337.06 129.46 336.69C129.22 338.02 129.13 338.78 129.13 339.56C129.13 340.39 128.47 341.08 127.64 341.11C127.36 341.12 123.9 341.11 122.84 341.11C122.01 341.11 121.33 340.45 121.29 339.62L120.79 327.16C120.76 326.3 121.42 325.58 122.28 325.55C123.17 325.52 123.86 326.18 123.89 327.04L124.33 338.02C124.95 338.02 125.58 338.02 126.12 338.02C126.23 337.06 126.45 335.89 126.8 334.04C126.89 333.56 127.21 333.15 127.65 332.93C128.09 332.72 128.61 332.73 129.04 332.96C130.45 333.71 131.72 334.4 132.86 335.02C135.66 336.55 138.57 338.14 139.32 338.03C140.26 337.94 140.86 337.83 141.24 337.73C141.23 337.72 141.23 337.72 141.22 337.71C138.48 335.16 137.45 333.32 135.9 330.53C135.36 329.56 134.75 328.46 133.97 327.16C133.53 326.42 133.77 325.47 134.5 325.03C135.23 324.59 136.19 324.83 136.63 325.56C137.44 326.91 138.06 328.03 138.61 329.02C140.12 331.73 140.95 333.23 143.33 335.44C144.55 336.57 144.98 337.69 144.61 338.77C144.04 340.46 141.9 340.89 139.68 341.11C139.56 341.12 139.41 341.13 139.26 341.13Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M90.4102 341.13C88.7602 341.13 86.5702 339.93 82.5402 337.74C81.9402 337.41 81.4802 337.06 80.8002 336.69C80.5502 338.08 80.6602 338.8 80.6602 339.56V341.05L78.9802 341.11C78.7002 341.12 75.1402 341.11 74.0902 341.11H72.5602L71.9802 327.16C71.9402 326.3 72.6002 325.58 73.4602 325.55C74.3502 325.52 75.0302 326.18 75.0702 327.04L75.5102 338.02C76.1302 338.02 76.7602 338.02 77.3002 338.02C77.4102 337.06 77.6302 335.89 77.9802 334.04L78.3802 331.98L80.2302 332.96C81.6402 333.71 82.9102 334.4 84.0502 335.02C86.8502 336.55 89.7402 338.13 90.5102 338.03C91.4502 337.94 92.0502 337.83 92.4302 337.73C92.4202 337.72 92.4202 337.72 92.4102 337.71C89.6702 335.16 88.6402 333.32 87.0902 330.52C86.5502 329.55 85.9402 328.45 85.1602 327.15C84.7202 326.41 84.9602 325.46 85.6902 325.02C86.4202 324.58 87.3802 324.82 87.8202 325.55C88.6302 326.9 89.2502 328.02 89.8002 329.01C91.3102 331.72 92.1402 333.22 94.5202 335.43C95.7402 336.56 96.1702 337.68 95.8002 338.76C95.2302 340.45 93.0902 340.88 90.8702 341.1C90.7002 341.12 90.5602 341.13 90.4102 341.13Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M103.08 77.3C102.55 77.3 102.03 77.02 101.74 76.53C101.31 75.79 101.56 74.84 102.3 74.41L104.57 73.09L104.2 62.6L105.24 62.21C105.4 62.15 109.29 60.6 109.79 56.68C110.69 49.65 107.03 39.21 106.99 39.11C106.7 38.3 107.13 37.42 107.93 37.13C108.74 36.84 109.62 37.27 109.91 38.07C110.07 38.53 113.85 49.31 112.86 57.07C112.31 61.4 109.07 63.7 107.37 64.62L107.72 74.84L103.85 77.09C103.61 77.23 103.34 77.3 103.08 77.3Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M76.1496 77.6299C75.6896 77.6299 75.2296 77.4199 74.9196 77.0299C69.6496 70.1899 71.0696 57.3899 79.2696 37.8999C83.2196 26.0899 90.4696 20.9599 100.82 22.6399C107.41 23.7099 111.65 26.4999 113.77 31.1699L114.01 31.6999L113.85 32.2499C112.2 37.8599 106.9 41.9699 100.34 42.7299C96.9396 43.1199 92.4096 42.4999 92.2196 42.4799C91.3696 42.3599 90.7796 41.5799 90.8996 40.7299C91.0196 39.8799 91.7996 39.2899 92.6496 39.4099C92.6896 39.4199 96.9796 39.9999 99.9896 39.6499C105.08 39.0599 109.22 36.0599 110.7 31.9299C108.95 28.5899 105.55 26.5499 100.33 25.6999C91.5696 24.2799 85.6396 28.5999 82.1996 38.9299L82.1596 39.0399C74.6296 56.9299 72.9796 69.4099 77.3796 75.1299C77.8996 75.8099 77.7796 76.7799 77.0996 77.3099C76.8196 77.5299 76.4896 77.6299 76.1496 77.6299Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M120.69 71.9799C120.41 71.9799 120.13 71.8999 119.88 71.7499C119.15 71.2999 118.93 70.3399 119.38 69.6099C120.75 67.3899 124.2 58.1699 110.99 32.5099C110.6 31.7499 110.9 30.8099 111.66 30.4199C112.42 30.0299 113.36 30.3299 113.75 31.0899C126.83 56.5099 124.54 67.1599 122.01 71.2399C121.71 71.7199 121.21 71.9799 120.69 71.9799Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M133.13 155.62L126.55 154.38L85.8502 147.89C83.6002 147.54 79.2602 145.62 79.0302 140.84C78.9602 139.26 77.8002 133.56 76.4602 126.96C74.0602 115.14 71.0702 100.44 70.9402 93.66C70.7402 83.46 75.8702 81.1399 79.6102 79.4499C80.1702 79.1999 80.7002 78.9599 81.1902 78.6999L90.8202 74.1999L90.6802 55.8699C90.6702 55.0099 91.3602 54.2 92.2202 54.2H92.2302C93.0802 54.2 93.7702 54.9899 93.7802 55.8499L93.9302 76.12L82.5502 81.4599C82.0502 81.7199 81.4502 81.9999 80.8802 82.2699C77.2802 83.8999 73.8802 85.4399 74.0302 93.5999C74.1502 100.1 77.2402 115.27 79.4802 126.35C80.9602 133.63 82.0302 138.89 82.1102 140.71C82.2702 144.14 86.1502 144.82 86.3202 144.84L127.06 151.34L132.95 152.45C133.48 152.26 134.64 151.8 136 150.91C136.72 150.44 137.68 150.64 138.15 151.36C138.62 152.08 138.42 153.04 137.7 153.51C135.4 155.02 133.52 155.53 133.45 155.56L133.13 155.62Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M90.8205 58.55C90.7805 58.55 90.7305 58.55 90.6805 58.54C87.2605 58.24 85.0305 56.79 84.0405 54.23C83.4805 52.77 83.5205 51.18 84.1505 49.75C84.7805 48.32 85.9405 47.23 87.4005 46.66C89.1205 46 91.0805 46.19 92.6405 47.18C93.3605 47.64 93.5805 48.6 93.1205 49.32C92.6605 50.04 91.7005 50.26 90.9805 49.8C90.2505 49.34 89.3305 49.24 88.5205 49.56C87.8305 49.82 87.2905 50.34 86.9905 51.01C86.6905 51.68 86.6705 52.43 86.9405 53.11C87.2805 53.99 88.0605 55.18 90.9605 55.44C91.8105 55.52 92.4405 56.27 92.3705 57.12C92.2905 57.95 91.6205 58.55 90.8205 58.55Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M103.41 206.39C102.77 206.39 102.17 205.99 101.95 205.36C101.66 204.55 102.08 203.67 102.89 203.38L111.86 200.18C112.66 199.89 113.55 200.31 113.84 201.12C114.13 201.93 113.71 202.82 112.9 203.1L103.93 206.3C103.76 206.36 103.58 206.39 103.41 206.39Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M88.26 328.01H82.8C81.94 328.01 81.25 327.31 81.25 326.46C81.25 325.6 81.94 324.91 82.8 324.91H85.55C88.06 307.07 103.38 206.47 103.54 205.43C103.67 204.58 104.46 204.04 105.31 204.16C106.16 204.29 106.74 205.1 106.61 205.94C106.45 207.01 90.25 313.12 88.45 326.71L88.26 328.01Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M129.64 328.46C128.82 328.46 128.14 327.82 128.09 327C128.04 326.14 128.69 325.41 129.55 325.36L133.38 325.14C131.57 301.94 132.68 280.39 133.75 259.54C135.07 233.91 136.32 209.71 131.79 186.06C131.63 185.22 132.18 184.41 133.02 184.25C133.87 184.09 134.67 184.64 134.83 185.48C139.43 209.49 138.17 233.88 136.84 259.7C135.75 280.92 134.62 302.87 136.59 326.47L136.72 328.06L129.72 328.47C129.7 328.46 129.67 328.46 129.64 328.46Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M107.39 106.94C106.55 106.94 105.86 106.24 105.84 105.39L105.6 95.08L90.5897 77.08C90.0397 76.42 90.1297 75.44 90.7897 74.89C91.4497 74.34 92.4197 74.43 92.9697 75.09L108.33 93.5C108.55 93.77 108.68 94.11 108.69 94.46L108.95 105.33C108.97 106.19 108.29 106.95 107.44 106.95C107.42 106.94 107.41 106.94 107.39 106.94Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M140.8 104.05C140.61 104.05 140.42 104.01 140.23 103.94C139.49 103.65 139.19 103.33 132.74 93.82C129.4 88.9 124.44 81.57 123.09 80.21C118.66 79.49 114.57 78.53 112.52 78.02L108.65 94.83C108.46 95.67 107.62 96.19 106.79 95.99C105.96 95.8 105.43 94.97 105.63 94.13L109.9 75.6C110.04 75 110.51 74.54 111.12 74.43C111.61 74.33 112.11 74.48 112.46 74.81C113.98 75.2 118.82 76.4 123.94 77.21C125.09 77.39 125.78 78.02 135.32 92.09C137.99 96.03 141.02 100.49 141.72 101.25C142.28 101.66 142.52 102.4 142.26 103.08C142 103.68 141.41 104.05 140.8 104.05Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M129.33 124.16C129.31 124.16 129.29 124.16 129.27 124.16C128.41 124.13 127.74 123.41 127.78 122.55L128.44 103.94C128.47 103.08 129.18 102.41 130.05 102.44C130.91 102.47 131.58 103.19 131.54 104.05L130.88 122.66C130.85 123.5 130.16 124.16 129.33 124.16Z" fill="black"/>
</g>
<g clip-path="url(#clip2)">
<path d="M417.05 136.93L406.78 126.66L417.05 116.39L427.33 126.66L417.05 136.93ZM410.06 126.65L417.04 133.63L424.02 126.65L417.04 119.67L410.06 126.65Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M427.16 254.91C427.16 256.55 425.83 257.88 424.19 257.88C422.55 257.88 421.21 256.55 421.21 254.91C421.21 253.27 422.54 251.93 424.19 251.93C425.83 251.93 427.16 253.27 427.16 254.91Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M397.14 163.18C397.14 164.76 395.85 166.05 394.27 166.05C392.68 166.05 391.4 164.77 391.4 163.18C391.4 161.59 392.69 160.31 394.27 160.31C395.86 160.31 397.14 161.59 397.14 163.18Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M445.01 223.39H412.43C411.57 223.39 410.88 222.69 410.88 221.84C410.88 220.98 411.57 220.29 412.43 220.29H445.01C445.87 220.29 446.56 220.99 446.56 221.84C446.57 222.7 445.87 223.39 445.01 223.39Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M414.76 202.45H398.47C397.61 202.45 396.92 201.75 396.92 200.9C396.92 200.04 397.62 199.35 398.47 199.35H414.76C415.62 199.35 416.31 200.05 416.31 200.9C416.32 201.75 415.62 202.45 414.76 202.45Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M324.28 132.36C324.2 132.36 324.12 132.35 324.04 132.34C323.19 132.21 322.61 131.42 322.74 130.57C322.99 128.96 328.82 91.2601 330.7 82.6901C330.63 81.3901 330.31 79.5001 330.09 78.2201C329.95 77.3701 330.52 76.5701 331.36 76.4301C332.21 76.2901 333.01 76.8601 333.15 77.7001C333.39 79.1201 333.75 81.2601 333.81 82.7501L333.82 82.9501L333.77 83.1501C331.97 91.2001 325.86 130.64 325.8 131.04C325.69 131.81 325.03 132.36 324.28 132.36Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M335.99 129.36C335.96 129.36 335.92 129.36 335.89 129.36C335.04 129.31 334.39 128.57 334.44 127.71C334.46 127.37 336.66 93.1402 336.43 84.4802L336.42 84.2102L338.12 78.9702C338.38 78.1602 339.26 77.7102 340.07 77.9702C340.89 78.2302 341.33 79.1102 341.07 79.9202L339.53 84.6502C339.72 93.8402 337.62 126.5 337.53 127.89C337.49 128.73 336.8 129.36 335.99 129.36Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M370.19 184.08C369.38 184.08 368.7 183.45 368.64 182.63L366.65 150.72C366.6 149.87 367.25 149.13 368.1 149.07C368.96 149.03 369.69 149.67 369.74 150.52L371.74 182.43C371.79 183.28 371.14 184.02 370.29 184.07C370.25 184.08 370.22 184.08 370.19 184.08Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M300.9 159.76C296.45 159.76 295.33 157.53 294.53 154.85C294.34 154.23 294.17 153.64 293.91 153.14C293.51 152.39 293.79 151.44 294.55 151.04C295.31 150.63 296.25 150.92 296.65 151.68C297.06 152.45 297.3 153.25 297.51 153.96C298.17 156.17 298.6 157.62 305.56 156C316.79 153.38 336.61 149.13 351.09 146.02C355.22 145.13 358.82 144.36 361.5 143.78C363.1 138.06 365.38 130.97 367.77 123.5C370.89 113.75 374.12 103.68 375.84 96.64C377.3 82.8 367.62 78.46 358.26 74.27L357.8 74.06C357.02 73.71 356.67 72.79 357.02 72.01C357.37 71.23 358.29 70.88 359.07 71.23L359.53 71.44C368.95 75.66 380.67 80.91 378.92 97.08C378.91 97.15 378.9 97.21 378.88 97.28C377.15 104.43 373.88 114.61 370.73 124.45C368.21 132.3 365.84 139.71 364.24 145.52C364.09 146.08 363.64 146.5 363.07 146.63C360.32 147.23 356.36 148.08 351.73 149.07C338.08 152 317.46 156.42 306.25 159.04C304.08 159.53 302.32 159.75 300.9 159.76Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M304.58 87.15C304.25 87.15 303.92 87.05 303.64 86.83C302.96 86.31 302.83 85.34 303.35 84.66L311 74.69C311.19 74.45 311.44 74.27 311.72 74.17L329 68.19C329.81 67.91 330.69 68.34 330.97 69.15C331.25 69.96 330.82 70.84 330.01 71.12L313.17 76.95L305.81 86.55C305.51 86.95 305.05 87.15 304.58 87.15Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M318.01 341.3H292.45L292.17 341.19C290.88 340.67 289.94 339.32 289.67 337.59C289.37 335.71 289.86 333.03 292.11 331.16C293.54 329.97 293.98 329.67 296.37 328.44C300.16 290 307.74 172.74 307.82 171.55C307.87 170.7 308.61 170.05 309.47 170.1C310.32 170.15 310.97 170.89 310.92 171.75C310.84 172.95 303.14 292 299.38 329.58L299.3 330.42L298.55 330.81C295.54 332.35 295.4 332.46 294.11 333.54C292.85 334.59 292.58 336.07 292.74 337.11C292.82 337.65 293.02 338.02 293.19 338.2H315.35C317.17 326.3 330.73 237.04 334.5 195.32L334.65 193.67L336.28 193.92C336.51 193.96 337.11 194.02 337.79 194.09C338.71 194.19 339.74 194.3 340.26 194.38L341.41 194.56L341.56 195.72C345.89 228.94 352.54 297.48 355.46 329.08L355.55 330.04L354.73 330.54C353.79 331.12 353.01 331.55 352.32 331.93C351.56 332.35 350.9 332.71 350.25 333.15C348.9 334.07 347.88 336.36 347.91 337.2C350.79 337.57 364.42 337.28 371.14 337.1L366.64 191.56C366.61 190.7 367.29 189.99 368.14 189.96C368.97 189.93 369.71 190.61 369.74 191.46L374.33 340.11L372.78 340.16C371.9 340.19 351.09 340.81 347.36 340.26C346.17 340.14 345.23 339.34 344.93 338.14C344.32 335.73 346.38 332.04 348.5 330.59C349.28 330.05 350.04 329.64 350.84 329.2C351.3 328.95 351.77 328.69 352.29 328.39C349.37 296.78 342.93 230.56 338.65 197.31C338.26 197.27 337.84 197.22 337.47 197.18C337.46 197.18 337.46 197.18 337.45 197.18C333.2 242.51 318.36 339 318.21 339.98L318.01 341.3Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M340.8 76.2C335.52 76.2 330.78 72.39 330.53 72.18L329.92 71.68L329.96 70.89C329.96 70.85 330.18 66.81 329.99 62.23C326.01 58.58 323.77 53.29 323.32 46.48C322.23 30.16 324.25 25.82 324.48 25.38C324.88 24.62 325.82 24.33 326.58 24.73C327.34 25.13 327.62 26.07 327.22 26.83C327.22 26.83 325.39 30.94 326.41 46.27C326.83 52.5 328.88 57.22 332.51 60.31L333.02 60.74L333.05 61.41C333.24 65.2 333.15 68.66 333.09 70.2C334.82 71.41 339.95 74.53 344.04 72.26C344.79 71.84 345.73 72.11 346.15 72.86C346.57 73.61 346.3 74.55 345.55 74.97C343.99 75.86 342.37 76.2 340.8 76.2Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M356.44 37.6301C356.36 37.6301 356.28 37.6201 356.2 37.6101C355.35 37.4801 354.78 36.6801 354.91 35.8401C354.92 35.7801 355.77 29.9201 352.75 23.5201C350.55 19.9301 344.93 16.7801 335.68 18.6501C331.75 19.4401 328.24 23.0001 327.16 27.2001C328.92 30.7401 334.68 31.0301 341.98 31.0301C347.36 31.0301 348.93 34.2801 349.01 36.0001C349.05 36.8601 348.39 37.5801 347.53 37.6201C346.68 37.6701 345.95 37.0001 345.91 36.1401C345.89 35.9701 345.6 34.1301 341.97 34.1301C335.06 34.1301 326.46 34.1301 324.07 27.9001L323.91 27.4701L324.01 27.0201C325.2 21.3701 329.74 16.6701 335.06 15.6001C345.95 13.4001 352.73 17.4501 355.44 21.9701L355.51 22.1001C359 29.4301 358.01 36.0301 357.97 36.3001C357.84 37.0901 357.19 37.6301 356.44 37.6301Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M340.03 197.19C339.94 197.19 339.85 197.18 339.75 197.17L331.56 195.7C330.72 195.55 330.15 194.74 330.31 193.9C330.46 193.06 331.26 192.49 332.11 192.65L340.3 194.12C341.14 194.27 341.7 195.08 341.55 195.92C341.42 196.67 340.76 197.19 340.03 197.19Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M359.76 74.86C359.48 74.86 359.19 74.78 358.93 74.62L351.95 70.21L350.75 51.39C350.7 50.53 351.35 49.8 352.2 49.74C353.04 49.69 353.79 50.33 353.85 51.19L354.95 68.43L360.59 72C361.31 72.46 361.53 73.42 361.07 74.14C360.77 74.6 360.27 74.86 359.76 74.86Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M351.02 52.2602C350.25 52.2602 349.58 51.6902 349.48 50.9002C349.37 50.0502 349.97 49.2702 350.83 49.1702C354.02 48.7702 354.77 47.4002 355.06 46.4102C355.55 44.7302 354.54 42.8802 352.81 42.3002C351.83 41.9702 350.81 42.1002 350.01 42.6702C349.31 43.1702 348.34 43.0002 347.85 42.3002C347.35 41.6002 347.52 40.6302 348.22 40.1402C349.81 39.0102 351.9 38.7202 353.81 39.3602C357.1 40.4702 359 44.0302 358.04 47.2802C357.47 49.2202 355.83 51.6602 351.22 52.2402C351.15 52.2502 351.08 52.2602 351.02 52.2602Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M369.77 185.38H355.03C354.17 185.38 353.48 184.68 353.48 183.83C353.48 182.97 354.17 182.28 355.03 182.28H369.77C370.63 182.28 371.32 182.98 371.32 183.83C371.33 184.69 370.63 185.38 369.77 185.38Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M309.57 143.44C309.28 143.44 308.98 143.36 308.73 143.19L299.76 137.42C299.04 136.96 298.83 136 299.29 135.28C299.75 134.56 300.71 134.35 301.43 134.81L309.84 140.21L347.87 130.51L357.26 97.14C357.49 96.32 358.35 95.84 359.17 96.07C360 96.3 360.47 97.16 360.24 97.98L350.6 132.21C350.45 132.74 350.03 133.16 349.49 133.29L309.94 143.38C309.83 143.42 309.7 143.44 309.57 143.44Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M293.62 149.47C293.01 149.47 292.43 149.11 292.18 148.51C291.86 147.72 292.24 146.81 293.03 146.49L300.34 143.5C301.13 143.18 302.04 143.56 302.36 144.35C302.69 145.14 302.3 146.05 301.51 146.37L294.2 149.36C294.01 149.43 293.81 149.47 293.62 149.47Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M314.02 157.16C313.37 157.16 312.76 156.75 312.55 156.1L309.89 148.12C309.62 147.31 310.06 146.43 310.87 146.16C311.69 145.89 312.56 146.33 312.83 147.14L315.49 155.12C315.76 155.93 315.32 156.81 314.51 157.08C314.35 157.14 314.18 157.16 314.02 157.16Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M334.98 63.53C332.78 63.53 331.16 63.02 331.03 62.98C330.21 62.72 329.77 61.84 330.03 61.03C330.29 60.22 331.16 59.76 331.98 60.03C332.01 60.04 336.05 61.27 339.36 59.34C340.1 58.91 341.05 59.16 341.48 59.9C341.91 60.64 341.66 61.59 340.92 62.02C338.9 63.2 336.75 63.53 334.98 63.53Z" fill="black"/>
<path id="lamp2"d="M223.57 212.53C223.16 212.53 222.77 212.47 222.48 212.19C222.19 211.9 222.02 211.56 222.02 211.15L221.49 126.35C221.49 126.16 221.52 125.98 221.6 125.8C222.7 122.96 225.38 121.26 228.77 121.26C230.17 121.26 231.62 121.56 232.97 122.12C233.68 122.42 234.54 122.84 235.52 123.34C238.32 124.73 242.14 126.64 244.99 126.65C252.57 126.65 258.72 120.51 258.75 112.97C258.76 109.31 257.34 105.86 254.76 103.26C252.18 100.66 248.74 99.2301 245.08 99.2201C241.92 99.2201 237.74 101.42 234.7 103.03C233.69 103.56 232.82 104.02 232.1 104.34C230.97 104.85 229.78 105.1 228.55 105.1C225.46 105.1 222.75 103.48 221.48 100.88C221.38 100.67 221.33 100.44 221.32 100.21L221 46.8001C221 46.3801 221.16 45.9801 221.46 45.6801C221.76 45.3901 222.17 45.2201 222.58 45.2401C238.21 45.6001 256.2 47.4501 271.18 58.4501C287.27 70.2601 295.7 85.1501 296.94 103.97C297.83 117.42 293.58 138.48 268.28 162.41C267.74 162.92 267.27 163.37 267.13 163.53C252.19 180.36 251.3 210.76 251.29 211.06C251.27 211.9 250.59 212.46 249.75 212.47L223.57 212.53C223.58 212.53 223.57 212.53 223.57 212.53ZM224.6 126.67L225.11 209.63L248.26 209.49C248.62 202.94 250.9 177.15 264.82 161.48C265.05 161.22 265.47 160.82 266.16 160.17C290.58 137.07 294.7 116.98 293.86 104.19C293.11 92.8001 289.75 75.9301 269.36 60.9601C255.58 50.8401 239.54 48.8401 224.11 48.3901L224.43 99.8201C225.23 101.15 226.81 102 228.56 102C229.34 102 230.11 101.83 230.84 101.51C231.47 101.23 232.3 100.79 233.26 100.28C236.6 98.5201 241.16 96.1101 245.07 96.1101C249.59 96.1201 253.81 97.8801 256.97 101.07C260.14 104.26 261.87 108.48 261.86 112.97C261.83 122.22 254.29 129.74 245.04 129.74C241.42 129.73 237.22 127.64 234.15 126.11C233.21 125.64 232.4 125.24 231.79 124.98C230.82 124.57 229.78 124.36 228.78 124.36C227.82 124.36 225.56 124.6 224.6 126.67Z" fill="red"/>
<path d="M226.57 225.72C225.72 225.72 225.02 224.88 225.02 224.02C225.01 223.16 225.7 222.22 226.56 222.21L247.47 221.83H247.48C248.33 221.83 249.03 222.69 249.03 223.54C249.04 224.4 248.35 225.33 247.49 225.34L226.57 225.72C226.58 225.72 226.57 225.72 226.57 225.72Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M227.13 239.68C226.28 239.68 225.58 238.97 225.58 238.12C225.57 237.26 226.27 236.62 227.12 236.62L242.9 236.58H242.91C243.76 236.58 244.46 237.2 244.46 238.06C244.47 238.92 243.77 239.6 242.92 239.6L227.13 239.68Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M312.36 130.31C311.51 130.31 310.82 129.59 310.81 128.74L310.48 98.6802C310.47 97.8202 311.16 96.9602 312.02 96.9602C312.02 96.9602 312.03 96.9602 312.04 96.9602C312.89 96.9602 313.58 97.7802 313.59 98.6302L313.92 128.65C313.93 129.51 313.24 130.32 312.39 130.32C312.37 130.31 312.36 130.31 312.36 130.31Z" fill="black"/>
</g>
<defs>
<clipPath id="clip0">
<rect y="75" width="460.76" height="266.82" fill="white"/>
</clipPath>
<clipPath id="clip1">
<rect x="70" width="207.82" height="341.13" fill="white"/>
</clipPath>
<clipPath id="clip2">
<rect x="221" y="15" width="225.57" height="326.3" fill="white"/>
</clipPath>
</defs>
</svg>
```

---

[image]

Внутри не должно быть пустоты и прорисовка - сплошной линией.

---

[image]

Нужно контур чтобы был без обводки - сплошной линией.

Comment: не понятно что нужно

Comment: Вставил код SVG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Пример  немного сложнее

После анимации прорисовки добавляется анимация движения половинки лампочки и передвигается жёлтый круг:

```
@keyframes lamp_tr {
0%{transform: translate(0, 0);}
100%{transform: translate(-16px, 21px);}
} 

.yell {
transform-origin:209.38,134.95;
transform-box:fill-box;
animation:yell 2s forwards 9s,puls 1s infinite 11s;
}
@keyframes yell {

0%{transform: translate(0, 0);}
100%{transform: translate(25px, -17px);}
}
```

```css
.lamp1 {
fill:none;
stroke:#111111;
stroke-dasharray:0,966;
animation:draw 10s linear forwards,lamp_fill 2s forwards 5s; 
}
@keyframes draw{
100% {stroke-dasharray:966,0;}
} 

@keyframes lamp_fill{
0% {fill:none;}
100% {fill:#111111;}
}  

.lamp2 {
fill:none;
stroke:#111111;
stroke-dasharray:0,966;
animation:draw2 5s linear forwards,lamp_fill 2s forwards 5s,lamp_tr 2s linear forwards 7s; 
}
@keyframes draw2{
100% {stroke-dasharray:966,0;}
} 

@keyframes lamp_fill{
0% {fill:none;}
100% {fill:#111111;}
}  

@keyframes lamp_tr {
0%{transform: translate(0, 0);}
100%{transform: translate(-16px, 21px);}
} 

.yell {
transform-origin:209.38,134.95;
transform-box:fill-box;
animation:yell 2s forwards 9s,puls 1s infinite 11s;
}
@keyframes yell {

0%{transform: translate(0, 0);}
100%{transform: translate(25px, -17px);}
}
```

```html
<svg width="461" height="342" viewBox="0 0 461 342" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<g> 
<path class="yell"    d="M261.34 150.95C261.34 192.89 227.34 226.9 185.39 226.9C143.44 226.9 109.44 192.9 109.44 150.95C109.45 109 143.45 75 185.4 75C227.34 75 261.34 109 261.34 150.95Z" fill="#F3EC18"/> 

<path d="M459.2 341.82H1.55C0.69 341.82 0 341.12 0 340.27C0 339.41 0.7 338.72 1.55 338.72H459.2C460.06 338.72 460.75 339.42 460.75 340.27C460.76 341.12 460.06 341.82 459.2 341.82Z" fill="black"/>
</g>
<g clip-path="url(#clip1)">
<path d="M123.85 153.28C123.78 153.28 123.71 153.28 123.64 153.27C122.79 153.15 122.2 152.37 122.32 151.52L122.82 147.91C122.94 147.06 123.72 146.47 124.57 146.58C125.42 146.7 126.01 147.48 125.9 148.33L125.4 151.94C125.28 152.72 124.61 153.28 123.85 153.28Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M123.75 143.44C123.62 143.44 123.48 143.42 123.36 143.39L93.0396 135.41C92.4596 135.26 92.0196 134.78 91.9096 134.19L85.9296 101.62C85.7696 100.78 86.3296 99.97 87.1796 99.81C88.0296 99.66 88.8296 100.21 88.9896 101.06L94.7896 132.66L123.57 140.23L127.66 138.09C128.42 137.69 129.36 137.99 129.76 138.75C130.16 139.51 129.86 140.45 129.1 140.84L124.48 143.26C124.25 143.38 124 143.44 123.75 143.44Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M215.62 17.01C214.76 17.01 214.07 16.32 214.07 15.46V1.55C214.07 0.69 214.77 0 215.62 0C216.48 0 217.17 0.69 217.17 1.55V15.46C217.18 16.32 216.48 17.01 215.62 17.01Z" fill="#1A1A1A"/>
<path d="M164.41 38.6901C164.01 38.6901 163.62 38.5401 163.31 38.2401L154.88 29.8101C154.27 29.2001 154.27 28.2201 154.88 27.6201C155.49 27.0101 156.47 27.0101 157.07 27.6201L165.5 36.0501C166.11 36.6601 166.11 37.6401 165.5 38.2401C165.2 38.5401 164.81 38.6901 164.41 38.6901Z" fill="#1A1A1A"/>
<path d="M268.141 36.6901C267.741 36.6901 267.351 36.5401 267.041 36.2401C266.431 35.6301 266.431 34.6501 267.041 34.0501L275.171 25.9201C275.781 25.3201 276.761 25.3101 277.361 25.9201C277.971 26.5301 277.971 27.5101 277.361 28.1101L269.231 36.2401C268.931 36.5401 268.531 36.6901 268.141 36.6901Z" fill="#1A1A1A"/>

<path  class="lamp2" d="M223.57 212.53C223.16 212.53 222.77 212.47 222.48 212.19C222.19 211.9 222.02 211.56 222.02 211.15L221.49 126.35C221.49 126.16 221.52 125.98 221.6 125.8C222.7 122.96 225.38 121.26 228.77 121.26C230.17 121.26 231.62 121.56 232.97 122.12C233.68 122.42 234.54 122.84 235.52 123.34C238.32 124.73 242.14 126.64 244.99 126.65C252.57 126.65 258.72 120.51 258.75 112.97C258.76 109.31 257.34 105.86 254.76 103.26C252.18 100.66 248.74 99.2301 245.08 99.2201C241.92 99.2201 237.74 101.42 234.7 103.03C233.69 103.56 232.82 104.02 232.1 104.34C230.97 104.85 229.78 105.1 228.55 105.1C225.46 105.1 222.75 103.48 221.48 100.88C221.38 100.67 221.33 100.44 221.32 100.21L221 46.8001C221 46.3801 221.16 45.9801 221.46 45.6801C221.76 45.3901 222.17 45.2201 222.58 45.2401C238.21 45.6001 256.2 47.4501 271.18 58.4501C287.27 70.2601 295.7 85.1501 296.94 103.97C297.83 117.42 293.58 138.48 268.28 162.41C267.74 162.92 267.27 163.37 267.13 163.53C252.19 180.36 251.3 210.76 251.29 211.06C251.27 211.9 250.59 212.46 249.75 212.47L223.57 212.53C223.58 212.53 223.57 212.53 223.57 212.53ZM224.6 126.67L225.11 209.63L248.26 209.49C248.62 202.94 250.9 177.15 264.82 161.48C265.05 161.22 265.47 160.82 266.16 160.17C290.58 137.07 294.7 116.98 293.86 104.19C293.11 92.8001 289.75 75.9301 269.36 60.9601C255.58 50.8401 239.54 48.8401 224.11 48.3901L224.43 99.8201C225.23 101.15 226.81 102 228.56 102C229.34 102 230.11 101.83 230.84 101.51C231.47 101.23 232.3 100.79 233.26 100.28C236.6 98.5201 241.16 96.1101 245.07 96.1101C249.59 96.1201 253.81 97.8801 256.97 101.07C260.14 104.26 261.87 108.48 261.86 112.97C261.83 122.22 254.29 129.74 245.04 129.74C241.42 129.73 237.22 127.64 234.15 126.11C233.21 125.64 232.4 125.24 231.79 124.98C230.82 124.57 229.78 124.36 228.78 124.36C227.82 124.36 225.56 124.6 224.6 126.67Z" fill="none" stroke="black"/> 

<path class="lamp2" d="M226.57 225.72C225.72 225.72 225.02 224.88 225.02 224.02C225.01 223.16 225.7 222.22 226.56 222.21L247.47 221.83H247.48C248.33 221.83 249.03 222.69 249.03 223.54C249.04 224.4 248.35 225.33 247.49 225.34L226.57 225.72C226.58 225.72 226.57 225.72 226.57 225.72Z" stroke="black" fill="none"/> 

<path class="lamp2" d="M227.13 239.68C226.28 239.68 225.58 238.97 225.58 238.12C225.57 237.26 226.27 236.62 227.12 236.62L242.9 236.58H242.91C243.76 236.58 244.46 237.2 244.46 238.06C244.47 238.92 243.77 239.6 242.92 239.6L227.13 239.68Z" stroke="black" fill="none"/>   

<path class="lamp1"  d="M189.89 234.13C189.08 234.13 188.4 233.5 188.35 232.68C188.33 232.34 185.81 198.72 166 182.55C152.11 171.2 142.91 152.89 142 134.76C141.11 116.97 146.48 100.14 157.13 87.39C168.01 74.36 183.58 66.7 200.97 65.83C201.27 65.81 201.57 65.8 201.92 65.79L202.3 65.78C203.16 65.74 203.87 66.4 203.91 67.25L206.19 112.79C206.19 112.84 206.19 112.89 206.19 112.93C206.12 114.64 206.66 116.19 207.73 117.3C209.15 118.78 211.34 119.23 213.11 118.35C214.1 117.86 215.16 117.01 216.38 116.02C219.46 113.54 223.29 110.45 229.55 110.14C229.85 110.12 230.15 110.12 230.45 110.12C239.85 110.12 247.01 117.05 247.85 126.97C248.41 133.6 245.83 137.91 243.57 140.37C240.44 143.77 235.97 145.72 231.31 145.72C230.91 145.72 230.5 145.72 230.1 145.68C225.49 145.34 220.93 143.44 217.27 141.91C216.29 141.5 215.37 141.12 214.58 140.82C212.82 140.16 210.95 140.61 209.6 141.98C208.48 143.12 207.84 144.75 207.87 146.45L212.13 231.46C212.15 231.87 212.01 232.27 211.73 232.58C211.45 232.88 211.07 233.07 210.66 233.09L189.98 234.13C189.95 234.13 189.92 234.13 189.89 234.13ZM200.89 68.9401C167.29 70.7501 143.32 98.94 145.1 134.61C145.97 151.89 154.72 169.34 167.96 180.15C186.58 195.36 190.59 223.97 191.31 230.95L208.96 230.07L204.78 146.56C204.74 143.98 205.69 141.54 207.4 139.81C209.6 137.58 212.78 136.84 215.68 137.93C216.52 138.25 217.48 138.64 218.48 139.06C221.94 140.5 226.24 142.3 230.35 142.61C230.68 142.63 231 142.65 231.33 142.65C235.12 142.65 238.76 141.06 241.3 138.3C243.14 136.3 245.24 132.75 244.77 127.25C244.07 119 238.19 113.24 230.47 113.24C230.22 113.24 229.97 113.25 229.72 113.26C224.46 113.52 221.21 116.15 218.34 118.46C217.03 119.52 215.79 120.52 214.49 121.16C213.44 121.68 212.32 121.94 211.16 121.94C209.06 121.94 206.99 121.04 205.49 119.47C203.85 117.76 203 115.43 203.09 112.9L200.89 68.9401Z" fill="none" stroke="black"/>  

<path class="lamp1" d="M193.64 247.17C192.82 247.17 192.13 246.53 192.09 245.7C192.05 244.84 192.71 244.12 193.56 244.07L212 243.15C212.84 243.12 213.59 243.77 213.63 244.62C213.67 245.48 213.01 246.2 212.16 246.25L193.71 247.17C193.7 247.16 193.67 247.17 193.64 247.17Z" stroke="black" fill="none"/>
<path class="lamp1" d="M201.06 260.79C200.24 260.79 199.55 260.15 199.51 259.32C199.47 258.46 200.13 257.73 200.98 257.69L212.19 257.13C213.04 257.09 213.77 257.75 213.81 258.6C213.85 259.46 213.19 260.18 212.34 260.23L201.13 260.79C201.11 260.79 201.09 260.79 201.06 260.79Z" stroke="black" fill="none"/>
<path d="M106.82 186.06C106.02 186.06 105.34 185.29 105.28 184.49L104.54 175.32C104.47 174.46 105.11 173.68 105.96 173.61C106.83 173.54 107.56 174.16 107.63 175.01L108.25 182.6C112.62 182.35 125.63 181.31 132.81 177.47C131.19 173.09 129.87 166.75 129.81 166.46C129.64 165.62 130.17 164.8 131.01 164.63C131.84 164.45 132.67 164.99 132.84 165.83C132.86 165.91 134.45 173.53 136.17 177.53C136.47 178.23 136.22 179.19 135.58 179.6C126.64 185.28 107.68 186.06 106.87 186.06C106.85 186.06 106.84 186.06 106.82 186.06Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M101.35 185.96C90.2696 185.96 75.4196 182.43 74.7996 182.28C74.0496 182.1 73.5396 181.39 73.6196 180.62C73.6996 179.86 75.4596 161.89 76.4596 155.6C76.5896 154.75 77.3996 154.18 78.2296 154.31C79.0796 154.44 79.6496 155.24 79.5196 156.08C78.6996 161.29 77.2796 175.15 76.8396 179.56C80.7396 180.42 92.4996 182.85 101.35 182.85C102.21 182.85 102.9 183.55 102.9 184.4C102.9 185.26 102.2 185.96 101.35 185.96Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M120.93 328.14C120.16 328.14 119.49 327.56 119.39 326.77C118.54 319.71 117.56 313.73 116.43 306.81C113.65 289.8 109.85 266.5 104.53 206.05C104.45 205.2 105.09 204.44 105.94 204.37C106.8 204.29 107.55 204.93 107.62 205.78C112.92 266.12 116.72 289.35 119.49 306.32C120.62 313.28 121.61 319.28 122.47 326.41C122.57 327.26 121.97 328.03 121.12 328.14C121.05 328.14 120.99 328.14 120.93 328.14Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M73.83 327.86C73.01 327.86 72.32 327.21 72.28 326.38C71.89 318.52 71.73 309.06 71.53 297.08C71.39 288.56 71.23 278.91 70.95 268.01C70.83 263.39 70.67 259.01 70.51 254.77C69.74 233.88 69.07 215.83 74.65 188.98C74.82 188.14 75.65 187.6 76.48 187.78C77.32 187.95 77.86 188.78 77.68 189.61C72.18 216.09 72.84 233.96 73.61 254.66C73.77 258.9 73.93 263.29 74.05 267.93C74.33 278.84 74.49 288.51 74.64 297.03C74.84 308.98 75 318.41 75.38 326.23C75.42 327.09 74.76 327.81 73.91 327.86C73.88 327.85 73.85 327.86 73.83 327.86Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M139.26 341.13C137.61 341.13 135.42 339.94 131.39 337.74C130.78 337.41 130.14 337.06 129.46 336.69C129.22 338.02 129.13 338.78 129.13 339.56C129.13 340.39 128.47 341.08 127.64 341.11C127.36 341.12 123.9 341.11 122.84 341.11C122.01 341.11 121.33 340.45 121.29 339.62L120.79 327.16C120.76 326.3 121.42 325.58 122.28 325.55C123.17 325.52 123.86 326.18 123.89 327.04L124.33 338.02C124.95 338.02 125.58 338.02 126.12 338.02C126.23 337.06 126.45 335.89 126.8 334.04C126.89 333.56 127.21 333.15 127.65 332.93C128.09 332.72 128.61 332.73 129.04 332.96C130.45 333.71 131.72 334.4 132.86 335.02C135.66 336.55 138.57 338.14 139.32 338.03C140.26 337.94 140.86 337.83 141.24 337.73C141.23 337.72 141.23 337.72 141.22 337.71C138.48 335.16 137.45 333.32 135.9 330.53C135.36 329.56 134.75 328.46 133.97 327.16C133.53 326.42 133.77 325.47 134.5 325.03C135.23 324.59 136.19 324.83 136.63 325.56C137.44 326.91 138.06 328.03 138.61 329.02C140.12 331.73 140.95 333.23 143.33 335.44C144.55 336.57 144.98 337.69 144.61 338.77C144.04 340.46 141.9 340.89 139.68 341.11C139.56 341.12 139.41 341.13 139.26 341.13Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M90.4102 341.13C88.7602 341.13 86.5702 339.93 82.5402 337.74C81.9402 337.41 81.4802 337.06 80.8002 336.69C80.5502 338.08 80.6602 338.8 80.6602 339.56V341.05L78.9802 341.11C78.7002 341.12 75.1402 341.11 74.0902 341.11H72.5602L71.9802 327.16C71.9402 326.3 72.6002 325.58 73.4602 325.55C74.3502 325.52 75.0302 326.18 75.0702 327.04L75.5102 338.02C76.1302 338.02 76.7602 338.02 77.3002 338.02C77.4102 337.06 77.6302 335.89 77.9802 334.04L78.3802 331.98L80.2302 332.96C81.6402 333.71 82.9102 334.4 84.0502 335.02C86.8502 336.55 89.7402 338.13 90.5102 338.03C91.4502 337.94 92.0502 337.83 92.4302 337.73C92.4202 337.72 92.4202 337.72 92.4102 337.71C89.6702 335.16 88.6402 333.32 87.0902 330.52C86.5502 329.55 85.9402 328.45 85.1602 327.15C84.7202 326.41 84.9602 325.46 85.6902 325.02C86.4202 324.58 87.3802 324.82 87.8202 325.55C88.6302 326.9 89.2502 328.02 89.8002 329.01C91.3102 331.72 92.1402 333.22 94.5202 335.43C95.7402 336.56 96.1702 337.68 95.8002 338.76C95.2302 340.45 93.0902 340.88 90.8702 341.1C90.7002 341.12 90.5602 341.13 90.4102 341.13Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M103.08 77.3C102.55 77.3 102.03 77.02 101.74 76.53C101.31 75.79 101.56 74.84 102.3 74.41L104.57 73.09L104.2 62.6L105.24 62.21C105.4 62.15 109.29 60.6 109.79 56.68C110.69 49.65 107.03 39.21 106.99 39.11C106.7 38.3 107.13 37.42 107.93 37.13C108.74 36.84 109.62 37.27 109.91 38.07C110.07 38.53 113.85 49.31 112.86 57.07C112.31 61.4 109.07 63.7 107.37 64.62L107.72 74.84L103.85 77.09C103.61 77.23 103.34 77.3 103.08 77.3Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M76.1496 77.6299C75.6896 77.6299 75.2296 77.4199 74.9196 77.0299C69.6496 70.1899 71.0696 57.3899 79.2696 37.8999C83.2196 26.0899 90.4696 20.9599 100.82 22.6399C107.41 23.7099 111.65 26.4999 113.77 31.1699L114.01 31.6999L113.85 32.2499C112.2 37.8599 106.9 41.9699 100.34 42.7299C96.9396 43.1199 92.4096 42.4999 92.2196 42.4799C91.3696 42.3599 90.7796 41.5799 90.8996 40.7299C91.0196 39.8799 91.7996 39.2899 92.6496 39.4099C92.6896 39.4199 96.9796 39.9999 99.9896 39.6499C105.08 39.0599 109.22 36.0599 110.7 31.9299C108.95 28.5899 105.55 26.5499 100.33 25.6999C91.5696 24.2799 85.6396 28.5999 82.1996 38.9299L82.1596 39.0399C74.6296 56.9299 72.9796 69.4099 77.3796 75.1299C77.8996 75.8099 77.7796 76.7799 77.0996 77.3099C76.8196 77.5299 76.4896 77.6299 76.1496 77.6299Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M120.69 71.9799C120.41 71.9799 120.13 71.8999 119.88 71.7499C119.15 71.2999 118.93 70.3399 119.38 69.6099C120.75 67.3899 124.2 58.1699 110.99 32.5099C110.6 31.7499 110.9 30.8099 111.66 30.4199C112.42 30.0299 113.36 30.3299 113.75 31.0899C126.83 56.5099 124.54 67.1599 122.01 71.2399C121.71 71.7199 121.21 71.9799 120.69 71.9799Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M133.13 155.62L126.55 154.38L85.8502 147.89C83.6002 147.54 79.2602 145.62 79.0302 140.84C78.9602 139.26 77.8002 133.56 76.4602 126.96C74.0602 115.14 71.0702 100.44 70.9402 93.66C70.7402 83.46 75.8702 81.1399 79.6102 79.4499C80.1702 79.1999 80.7002 78.9599 81.1902 78.6999L90.8202 74.1999L90.6802 55.8699C90.6702 55.0099 91.3602 54.2 92.2202 54.2H92.2302C93.0802 54.2 93.7702 54.9899 93.7802 55.8499L93.9302 76.12L82.5502 81.4599C82.0502 81.7199 81.4502 81.9999 80.8802 82.2699C77.2802 83.8999 73.8802 85.4399 74.0302 93.5999C74.1502 100.1 77.2402 115.27 79.4802 126.35C80.9602 133.63 82.0302 138.89 82.1102 140.71C82.2702 144.14 86.1502 144.82 86.3202 144.84L127.06 151.34L132.95 152.45C133.48 152.26 134.64 151.8 136 150.91C136.72 150.44 137.68 150.64 138.15 151.36C138.62 152.08 138.42 153.04 137.7 153.51C135.4 155.02 133.52 155.53 133.45 155.56L133.13 155.62Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M90.8205 58.55C90.7805 58.55 90.7305 58.55 90.6805 58.54C87.2605 58.24 85.0305 56.79 84.0405 54.23C83.4805 52.77 83.5205 51.18 84.1505 49.75C84.7805 48.32 85.9405 47.23 87.4005 46.66C89.1205 46 91.0805 46.19 92.6405 47.18C93.3605 47.64 93.5805 48.6 93.1205 49.32C92.6605 50.04 91.7005 50.26 90.9805 49.8C90.2505 49.34 89.3305 49.24 88.5205 49.56C87.8305 49.82 87.2905 50.34 86.9905 51.01C86.6905 51.68 86.6705 52.43 86.9405 53.11C87.2805 53.99 88.0605 55.18 90.9605 55.44C91.8105 55.52 92.4405 56.27 92.3705 57.12C92.2905 57.95 91.6205 58.55 90.8205 58.55Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M103.41 206.39C102.77 206.39 102.17 205.99 101.95 205.36C101.66 204.55 102.08 203.67 102.89 203.38L111.86 200.18C112.66 199.89 113.55 200.31 113.84 201.12C114.13 201.93 113.71 202.82 112.9 203.1L103.93 206.3C103.76 206.36 103.58 206.39 103.41 206.39Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M88.26 328.01H82.8C81.94 328.01 81.25 327.31 81.25 326.46C81.25 325.6 81.94 324.91 82.8 324.91H85.55C88.06 307.07 103.38 206.47 103.54 205.43C103.67 204.58 104.46 204.04 105.31 204.16C106.16 204.29 106.74 205.1 106.61 205.94C106.45 207.01 90.25 313.12 88.45 326.71L88.26 328.01Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M129.64 328.46C128.82 328.46 128.14 327.82 128.09 327C128.04 326.14 128.69 325.41 129.55 325.36L133.38 325.14C131.57 301.94 132.68 280.39 133.75 259.54C135.07 233.91 136.32 209.71 131.79 186.06C131.63 185.22 132.18 184.41 133.02 184.25C133.87 184.09 134.67 184.64 134.83 185.48C139.43 209.49 138.17 233.88 136.84 259.7C135.75 280.92 134.62 302.87 136.59 326.47L136.72 328.06L129.72 328.47C129.7 328.46 129.67 328.46 129.64 328.46Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M107.39 106.94C106.55 106.94 105.86 106.24 105.84 105.39L105.6 95.08L90.5897 77.08C90.0397 76.42 90.1297 75.44 90.7897 74.89C91.4497 74.34 92.4197 74.43 92.9697 75.09L108.33 93.5C108.55 93.77 108.68 94.11 108.69 94.46L108.95 105.33C108.97 106.19 108.29 106.95 107.44 106.95C107.42 106.94 107.41 106.94 107.39 106.94Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M140.8 104.05C140.61 104.05 140.42 104.01 140.23 103.94C139.49 103.65 139.19 103.33 132.74 93.82C129.4 88.9 124.44 81.57 123.09 80.21C118.66 79.49 114.57 78.53 112.52 78.02L108.65 94.83C108.46 95.67 107.62 96.19 106.79 95.99C105.96 95.8 105.43 94.97 105.63 94.13L109.9 75.6C110.04 75 110.51 74.54 111.12 74.43C111.61 74.33 112.11 74.48 112.46 74.81C113.98 75.2 118.82 76.4 123.94 77.21C125.09 77.39 125.78 78.02 135.32 92.09C137.99 96.03 141.02 100.49 141.72 101.25C142.28 101.66 142.52 102.4 142.26 103.08C142 103.68 141.41 104.05 140.8 104.05Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M129.33 124.16C129.31 124.16 129.29 124.16 129.27 124.16C128.41 124.13 127.74 123.41 127.78 122.55L128.44 103.94C128.47 103.08 129.18 102.41 130.05 102.44C130.91 102.47 131.58 103.19 131.54 104.05L130.88 122.66C130.85 123.5 130.16 124.16 129.33 124.16Z" fill="black"/>
</g>
<g clip-path="url(#clip2)">
<path d="M417.05 136.93L406.78 126.66L417.05 116.39L427.33 126.66L417.05 136.93ZM410.06 126.65L417.04 133.63L424.02 126.65L417.04 119.67L410.06 126.65Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M427.16 254.91C427.16 256.55 425.83 257.88 424.19 257.88C422.55 257.88 421.21 256.55 421.21 254.91C421.21 253.27 422.54 251.93 424.19 251.93C425.83 251.93 427.16 253.27 427.16 254.91Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M397.14 163.18C397.14 164.76 395.85 166.05 394.27 166.05C392.68 166.05 391.4 164.77 391.4 163.18C391.4 161.59 392.69 160.31 394.27 160.31C395.86 160.31 397.14 161.59 397.14 163.18Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M445.01 223.39H412.43C411.57 223.39 410.88 222.69 410.88 221.84C410.88 220.98 411.57 220.29 412.43 220.29H445.01C445.87 220.29 446.56 220.99 446.56 221.84C446.57 222.7 445.87 223.39 445.01 223.39Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M414.76 202.45H398.47C397.61 202.45 396.92 201.75 396.92 200.9C396.92 200.04 397.62 199.35 398.47 199.35H414.76C415.62 199.35 416.31 200.05 416.31 200.9C416.32 201.75 415.62 202.45 414.76 202.45Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M324.28 132.36C324.2 132.36 324.12 132.35 324.04 132.34C323.19 132.21 322.61 131.42 322.74 130.57C322.99 128.96 328.82 91.2601 330.7 82.6901C330.63 81.3901 330.31 79.5001 330.09 78.2201C329.95 77.3701 330.52 76.5701 331.36 76.4301C332.21 76.2901 333.01 76.8601 333.15 77.7001C333.39 79.1201 333.75 81.2601 333.81 82.7501L333.82 82.9501L333.77 83.1501C331.97 91.2001 325.86 130.64 325.8 131.04C325.69 131.81 325.03 132.36 324.28 132.36Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M335.99 129.36C335.96 129.36 335.92 129.36 335.89 129.36C335.04 129.31 334.39 128.57 334.44 127.71C334.46 127.37 336.66 93.1402 336.43 84.4802L336.42 84.2102L338.12 78.9702C338.38 78.1602 339.26 77.7102 340.07 77.9702C340.89 78.2302 341.33 79.1102 341.07 79.9202L339.53 84.6502C339.72 93.8402 337.62 126.5 337.53 127.89C337.49 128.73 336.8 129.36 335.99 129.36Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M370.19 184.08C369.38 184.08 368.7 183.45 368.64 182.63L366.65 150.72C366.6 149.87 367.25 149.13 368.1 149.07C368.96 149.03 369.69 149.67 369.74 150.52L371.74 182.43C371.79 183.28 371.14 184.02 370.29 184.07C370.25 184.08 370.22 184.08 370.19 184.08Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M300.9 159.76C296.45 159.76 295.33 157.53 294.53 154.85C294.34 154.23 294.17 153.64 293.91 153.14C293.51 152.39 293.79 151.44 294.55 151.04C295.31 150.63 296.25 150.92 296.65 151.68C297.06 152.45 297.3 153.25 297.51 153.96C298.17 156.17 298.6 157.62 305.56 156C316.79 153.38 336.61 149.13 351.09 146.02C355.22 145.13 358.82 144.36 361.5 143.78C363.1 138.06 365.38 130.97 367.77 123.5C370.89 113.75 374.12 103.68 375.84 96.64C377.3 82.8 367.62 78.46 358.26 74.27L357.8 74.06C357.02 73.71 356.67 72.79 357.02 72.01C357.37 71.23 358.29 70.88 359.07 71.23L359.53 71.44C368.95 75.66 380.67 80.91 378.92 97.08C378.91 97.15 378.9 97.21 378.88 97.28C377.15 104.43 373.88 114.61 370.73 124.45C368.21 132.3 365.84 139.71 364.24 145.52C364.09 146.08 363.64 146.5 363.07 146.63C360.32 147.23 356.36 148.08 351.73 149.07C338.08 152 317.46 156.42 306.25 159.04C304.08 159.53 302.32 159.75 300.9 159.76Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M304.58 87.15C304.25 87.15 303.92 87.05 303.64 86.83C302.96 86.31 302.83 85.34 303.35 84.66L311 74.69C311.19 74.45 311.44 74.27 311.72 74.17L329 68.19C329.81 67.91 330.69 68.34 330.97 69.15C331.25 69.96 330.82 70.84 330.01 71.12L313.17 76.95L305.81 86.55C305.51 86.95 305.05 87.15 304.58 87.15Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M318.01 341.3H292.45L292.17 341.19C290.88 340.67 289.94 339.32 289.67 337.59C289.37 335.71 289.86 333.03 292.11 331.16C293.54 329.97 293.98 329.67 296.37 328.44C300.16 290 307.74 172.74 307.82 171.55C307.87 170.7 308.61 170.05 309.47 170.1C310.32 170.15 310.97 170.89 310.92 171.75C310.84 172.95 303.14 292 299.38 329.58L299.3 330.42L298.55 330.81C295.54 332.35 295.4 332.46 294.11 333.54C292.85 334.59 292.58 336.07 292.74 337.11C292.82 337.65 293.02 338.02 293.19 338.2H315.35C317.17 326.3 330.73 237.04 334.5 195.32L334.65 193.67L336.28 193.92C336.51 193.96 337.11 194.02 337.79 194.09C338.71 194.19 339.74 194.3 340.26 194.38L341.41 194.56L341.56 195.72C345.89 228.94 352.54 297.48 355.46 329.08L355.55 330.04L354.73 330.54C353.79 331.12 353.01 331.55 352.32 331.93C351.56 332.35 350.9 332.71 350.25 333.15C348.9 334.07 347.88 336.36 347.91 337.2C350.79 337.57 364.42 337.28 371.14 337.1L366.64 191.56C366.61 190.7 367.29 189.99 368.14 189.96C368.97 189.93 369.71 190.61 369.74 191.46L374.33 340.11L372.78 340.16C371.9 340.19 351.09 340.81 347.36 340.26C346.17 340.14 345.23 339.34 344.93 338.14C344.32 335.73 346.38 332.04 348.5 330.59C349.28 330.05 350.04 329.64 350.84 329.2C351.3 328.95 351.77 328.69 352.29 328.39C349.37 296.78 342.93 230.56 338.65 197.31C338.26 197.27 337.84 197.22 337.47 197.18C337.46 197.18 337.46 197.18 337.45 197.18C333.2 242.51 318.36 339 318.21 339.98L318.01 341.3Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M340.8 76.2C335.52 76.2 330.78 72.39 330.53 72.18L329.92 71.68L329.96 70.89C329.96 70.85 330.18 66.81 329.99 62.23C326.01 58.58 323.77 53.29 323.32 46.48C322.23 30.16 324.25 25.82 324.48 25.38C324.88 24.62 325.82 24.33 326.58 24.73C327.34 25.13 327.62 26.07 327.22 26.83C327.22 26.83 325.39 30.94 326.41 46.27C326.83 52.5 328.88 57.22 332.51 60.31L333.02 60.74L333.05 61.41C333.24 65.2 333.15 68.66 333.09 70.2C334.82 71.41 339.95 74.53 344.04 72.26C344.79 71.84 345.73 72.11 346.15 72.86C346.57 73.61 346.3 74.55 345.55 74.97C343.99 75.86 342.37 76.2 340.8 76.2Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M356.44 37.6301C356.36 37.6301 356.28 37.6201 356.2 37.6101C355.35 37.4801 354.78 36.6801 354.91 35.8401C354.92 35.7801 355.77 29.9201 352.75 23.5201C350.55 19.9301 344.93 16.7801 335.68 18.6501C331.75 19.4401 328.24 23.0001 327.16 27.2001C328.92 30.7401 334.68 31.0301 341.98 31.0301C347.36 31.0301 348.93 34.2801 349.01 36.0001C349.05 36.8601 348.39 37.5801 347.53 37.6201C346.68 37.6701 345.95 37.0001 345.91 36.1401C345.89 35.9701 345.6 34.1301 341.97 34.1301C335.06 34.1301 326.46 34.1301 324.07 27.9001L323.91 27.4701L324.01 27.0201C325.2 21.3701 329.74 16.6701 335.06 15.6001C345.95 13.4001 352.73 17.4501 355.44 21.9701L355.51 22.1001C359 29.4301 358.01 36.0301 357.97 36.3001C357.84 37.0901 357.19 37.6301 356.44 37.6301Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M340.03 197.19C339.94 197.19 339.85 197.18 339.75 197.17L331.56 195.7C330.72 195.55 330.15 194.74 330.31 193.9C330.46 193.06 331.26 192.49 332.11 192.65L340.3 194.12C341.14 194.27 341.7 195.08 341.55 195.92C341.42 196.67 340.76 197.19 340.03 197.19Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M359.76 74.86C359.48 74.86 359.19 74.78 358.93 74.62L351.95 70.21L350.75 51.39C350.7 50.53 351.35 49.8 352.2 49.74C353.04 49.69 353.79 50.33 353.85 51.19L354.95 68.43L360.59 72C361.31 72.46 361.53 73.42 361.07 74.14C360.77 74.6 360.27 74.86 359.76 74.86Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M351.02 52.2602C350.25 52.2602 349.58 51.6902 349.48 50.9002C349.37 50.0502 349.97 49.2702 350.83 49.1702C354.02 48.7702 354.77 47.4002 355.06 46.4102C355.55 44.7302 354.54 42.8802 352.81 42.3002C351.83 41.9702 350.81 42.1002 350.01 42.6702C349.31 43.1702 348.34 43.0002 347.85 42.3002C347.35 41.6002 347.52 40.6302 348.22 40.1402C349.81 39.0102 351.9 38.7202 353.81 39.3602C357.1 40.4702 359 44.0302 358.04 47.2802C357.47 49.2202 355.83 51.6602 351.22 52.2402C351.15 52.2502 351.08 52.2602 351.02 52.2602Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M369.77 185.38H355.03C354.17 185.38 353.48 184.68 353.48 183.83C353.48 182.97 354.17 182.28 355.03 182.28H369.77C370.63 182.28 371.32 182.98 371.32 183.83C371.33 184.69 370.63 185.38 369.77 185.38Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M309.57 143.44C309.28 143.44 308.98 143.36 308.73 143.19L299.76 137.42C299.04 136.96 298.83 136 299.29 135.28C299.75 134.56 300.71 134.35 301.43 134.81L309.84 140.21L347.87 130.51L357.26 97.14C357.49 96.32 358.35 95.84 359.17 96.07C360 96.3 360.47 97.16 360.24 97.98L350.6 132.21C350.45 132.74 350.03 133.16 349.49 133.29L309.94 143.38C309.83 143.42 309.7 143.44 309.57 143.44Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M293.62 149.47C293.01 149.47 292.43 149.11 292.18 148.51C291.86 147.72 292.24 146.81 293.03 146.49L300.34 143.5C301.13 143.18 302.04 143.56 302.36 144.35C302.69 145.14 302.3 146.05 301.51 146.37L294.2 149.36C294.01 149.43 293.81 149.47 293.62 149.47Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M314.02 157.16C313.37 157.16 312.76 156.75 312.55 156.1L309.89 148.12C309.62 147.31 310.06 146.43 310.87 146.16C311.69 145.89 312.56 146.33 312.83 147.14L315.49 155.12C315.76 155.93 315.32 156.81 314.51 157.08C314.35 157.14 314.18 157.16 314.02 157.16Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M334.98 63.53C332.78 63.53 331.16 63.02 331.03 62.98C330.21 62.72 329.77 61.84 330.03 61.03C330.29 60.22 331.16 59.76 331.98 60.03C332.01 60.04 336.05 61.27 339.36 59.34C340.1 58.91 341.05 59.16 341.48 59.9C341.91 60.64 341.66 61.59 340.92 62.02C338.9 63.2 336.75 63.53 334.98 63.53Z" fill="black"/>



<path d="M312.36 130.31C311.51 130.31 310.82 129.59 310.81 128.74L310.48 98.6802C310.47 97.8202 311.16 96.9602 312.02 96.9602C312.02 96.9602 312.03 96.9602 312.04 96.9602C312.89 96.9602 313.58 97.7802 313.59 98.6302L313.92 128.65C313.93 129.51 313.24 130.32 312.39 130.32C312.37 130.31 312.36 130.31 312.36 130.31Z" fill="black"/>
</g>

</svg>
```

Связанный вопрос: [Анимация рисования линиями изображений SVG](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1132337/28748)

Answer (score 4):

Только если так

```css
#lamp1,
#lamp2 {
  fill: none;
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 3;
  stroke-dashoffset: 967;
  stroke-dasharray: 0 0 967;
  animation: draw 10s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes draw {
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 0 967;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dasharray: 967 0 967;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg width="461" viewBox="0 0 461 342" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<g clip-path="url(#clip0)">
<path d="M261.34 150.95C261.34 192.89 227.34 226.9 185.39 226.9C143.44 226.9 109.44 192.9 109.44 150.95C109.45 109 143.45 75 185.4 75C227.34 75 261.34 109 261.34 150.95Z" fill="#F3EC18"/>
  
<path d="M459.2 341.82H1.55C0.69 341.82 0 341.12 0 340.27C0 339.41 0.7 338.72 1.55 338.72H459.2C460.06 338.72 460.75 339.42 460.75 340.27C460.76 341.12 460.06 341.82 459.2 341.82Z" fill="black"/>
</g>
<g clip-path="url(#clip1)">
<path d="M123.85 153.28C123.78 153.28 123.71 153.28 123.64 153.27C122.79 153.15 122.2 152.37 122.32 151.52L122.82 147.91C122.94 147.06 123.72 146.47 124.57 146.58C125.42 146.7 126.01 147.48 125.9 148.33L125.4 151.94C125.28 152.72 124.61 153.28 123.85 153.28Z" fill="black"/>
  
<path d="M123.75 143.44C123.62 143.44 123.48 143.42 123.36 143.39L93.0396 135.41C92.4596 135.26 92.0196 134.78 91.9096 134.19L85.9296 101.62C85.7696 100.78 86.3296 99.97 87.1796 99.81C88.0296 99.66 88.8296 100.21 88.9896 101.06L94.7896 132.66L123.57 140.23L127.66 138.09C128.42 137.69 129.36 137.99 129.76 138.75C130.16 139.51 129.86 140.45 129.1 140.84L124.48 143.26C124.25 143.38 124 143.44 123.75 143.44Z" fill="black"/>
  
<path d="M215.62 17.01C214.76 17.01 214.07 16.32 214.07 15.46V1.55C214.07 0.69 214.77 0 215.62 0C216.48 0 217.17 0.69 217.17 1.55V15.46C217.18 16.32 216.48 17.01 215.62 17.01Z" fill="#1A1A1A"/>
  
<path d="M164.41 38.6901C164.01 38.6901 163.62 38.5401 163.31 38.2401L154.88 29.8101C154.27 29.2001 154.27 28.2201 154.88 27.6201C155.49 27.0101 156.47 27.0101 157.07 27.6201L165.5 36.0501C166.11 36.6601 166.11 37.6401 165.5 38.2401C165.2 38.5401 164.81 38.6901 164.41 38.6901Z" fill="#1A1A1A"/>
  
<path d="M268.141 36.6901C267.741 36.6901 267.351 36.5401 267.041 36.2401C266.431 35.6301 266.431 34.6501 267.041 34.0501L275.171 25.9201C275.781 25.3201 276.761 25.3101 277.361 25.9201C277.971 26.5301 277.971 27.5101 277.361 28.1101L269.231 36.2401C268.931 36.5401 268.531 36.6901 268.141 36.6901Z" fill="#1A1A1A"/>
  
<path id="lamp1" d="M189.89 234.13C189.08 234.13 188.4 233.5 188.35 232.68C188.33 232.34 185.81 198.72 166 182.55C152.11 171.2 142.91 152.89 142 134.76C141.11 116.97 146.48 100.14 157.13 87.39C168.01 74.36 183.58 66.7 200.97 65.83C201.27 65.81 201.57 65.8 201.92 65.79L202.3 65.78C203.16 65.74 203.87 66.4 203.91 67.25L206.19 112.79C206.19 112.84 206.19 112.89 206.19 112.93C206.12 114.64 206.66 116.19 207.73 117.3C209.15 118.78 211.34 119.23 213.11 118.35C214.1 117.86 215.16 117.01 216.38 116.02C219.46 113.54 223.29 110.45 229.55 110.14C229.85 110.12 230.15 110.12 230.45 110.12C239.85 110.12 247.01 117.05 247.85 126.97C248.41 133.6 245.83 137.91 243.57 140.37C240.44 143.77 235.97 145.72 231.31 145.72C230.91 145.72 230.5 145.72 230.1 145.68C225.49 145.34 220.93 143.44 217.27 141.91C216.29 141.5 215.37 141.12 214.58 140.82C212.82 140.16 210.95 140.61 209.6 141.98C208.48 143.12 207.84 144.75 207.87 146.45L212.13 231.46C212.15 231.87 212.01 232.27 211.73 232.58C211.45 232.88 211.07 233.07 210.66 233.09L189.98 234.13C189.95 234.13 189.92 234.13 189.89 234.13Z" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="3"/>
  
<path d="M193.64 247.17C192.82 247.17 192.13 246.53 192.09 245.7C192.05 244.84 192.71 244.12 193.56 244.07L212 243.15C212.84 243.12 213.59 243.77 213.63 244.62C213.67 245.48 213.01 246.2 212.16 246.25L193.71 247.17C193.7 247.16 193.67 247.17 193.64 247.17Z" fill="black"/>
  
<path d="M201.06 260.79C200.24 260.79 199.55 260.15 199.51 259.32C199.47 258.46 200.13 257.73 200.98 257.69L212.19 257.13C213.04 257.09 213.77 257.75 213.81 258.6C213.85 259.46 213.19 260.18 212.34 260.23L201.13 260.79C201.11 260.79 201.09 260.79 201.06 260.79Z" fill="black"/>
  
<path d="M106.82 186.06C106.02 186.06 105.34 185.29 105.28 184.49L104.54 175.32C104.47 174.46 105.11 173.68 105.96 173.61C106.83 173.54 107.56 174.16 107.63 175.01L108.25 182.6C112.62 182.35 125.63 181.31 132.81 177.47C131.19 173.09 129.87 166.75 129.81 166.46C129.64 165.62 130.17 164.8 131.01 164.63C131.84 164.45 132.67 164.99 132.84 165.83C132.86 165.91 134.45 173.53 136.17 177.53C136.47 178.23 136.22 179.19 135.58 179.6C126.64 185.28 107.68 186.06 106.87 186.06C106.85 186.06 106.84 186.06 106.82 186.06Z" fill="black"/>
  
<path d="M101.35 185.96C90.2696 185.96 75.4196 182.43 74.7996 182.28C74.0496 182.1 73.5396 181.39 73.6196 180.62C73.6996 179.86 75.4596 161.89 76.4596 155.6C76.5896 154.75 77.3996 154.18 78.2296 154.31C79.0796 154.44 79.6496 155.24 79.5196 156.08C78.6996 161.29 77.2796 175.15 76.8396 179.56C80.7396 180.42 92.4996 182.85 101.35 182.85C102.21 182.85 102.9 183.55 102.9 184.4C102.9 185.26 102.2 185.96 101.35 185.96Z" fill="black"/>
  
<path d="M120.93 328.14C120.16 328.14 119.49 327.56 119.39 326.77C118.54 319.71 117.56 313.73 116.43 306.81C113.65 289.8 109.85 266.5 104.53 206.05C104.45 205.2 105.09 204.44 105.94 204.37C106.8 204.29 107.55 204.93 107.62 205.78C112.92 266.12 116.72 289.35 119.49 306.32C120.62 313.28 121.61 319.28 122.47 326.41C122.57 327.26 121.97 328.03 121.12 328.14C121.05 328.14 120.99 328.14 120.93 328.14Z" fill="black"/>
  
<path d="M73.83 327.86C73.01 327.86 72.32 327.21 72.28 326.38C71.89 318.52 71.73 309.06 71.53 297.08C71.39 288.56 71.23 278.91 70.95 268.01C70.83 263.39 70.67 259.01 70.51 254.77C69.74 233.88 69.07 215.83 74.65 188.98C74.82 188.14 75.65 187.6 76.48 187.78C77.32 187.95 77.86 188.78 77.68 189.61C72.18 216.09 72.84 233.96 73.61 254.66C73.77 258.9 73.93 263.29 74.05 267.93C74.33 278.84 74.49 288.51 74.64 297.03C74.84 308.98 75 318.41 75.38 326.23C75.42 327.09 74.76 327.81 73.91 327.86C73.88 327.85 73.85 327.86 73.83 327.86Z" fill="black"/>
  
<path d="M139.26 341.13C137.61 341.13 135.42 339.94 131.39 337.74C130.78 337.41 130.14 337.06 129.46 336.69C129.22 338.02 129.13 338.78 129.13 339.56C129.13 340.39 128.47 341.08 127.64 341.11C127.36 341.12 123.9 341.11 122.84 341.11C122.01 341.11 121.33 340.45 121.29 339.62L120.79 327.16C120.76 326.3 121.42 325.58 122.28 325.55C123.17 325.52 123.86 326.18 123.89 327.04L124.33 338.02C124.95 338.02 125.58 338.02 126.12 338.02C126.23 337.06 126.45 335.89 126.8 334.04C126.89 333.56 127.21 333.15 127.65 332.93C128.09 332.72 128.61 332.73 129.04 332.96C130.45 333.71 131.72 334.4 132.86 335.02C135.66 336.55 138.57 338.14 139.32 338.03C140.26 337.94 140.86 337.83 141.24 337.73C141.23 337.72 141.23 337.72 141.22 337.71C138.48 335.16 137.45 333.32 135.9 330.53C135.36 329.56 134.75 328.46 133.97 327.16C133.53 326.42 133.77 325.47 134.5 325.03C135.23 324.59 136.19 324.83 136.63 325.56C137.44 326.91 138.06 328.03 138.61 329.02C140.12 331.73 140.95 333.23 143.33 335.44C144.55 336.57 144.98 337.69 144.61 338.77C144.04 340.46 141.9 340.89 139.68 341.11C139.56 341.12 139.41 341.13 139.26 341.13Z" fill="black"/>
  
<path d="M90.4102 341.13C88.7602 341.13 86.5702 339.93 82.5402 337.74C81.9402 337.41 81.4802 337.06 80.8002 336.69C80.5502 338.08 80.6602 338.8 80.6602 339.56V341.05L78.9802 341.11C78.7002 341.12 75.1402 341.11 74.0902 341.11H72.5602L71.9802 327.16C71.9402 326.3 72.6002 325.58 73.4602 325.55C74.3502 325.52 75.0302 326.18 75.0702 327.04L75.5102 338.02C76.1302 338.02 76.7602 338.02 77.3002 338.02C77.4102 337.06 77.6302 335.89 77.9802 334.04L78.3802 331.98L80.2302 332.96C81.6402 333.71 82.9102 334.4 84.0502 335.02C86.8502 336.55 89.7402 338.13 90.5102 338.03C91.4502 337.94 92.0502 337.83 92.4302 337.73C92.4202 337.72 92.4202 337.72 92.4102 337.71C89.6702 335.16 88.6402 333.32 87.0902 330.52C86.5502 329.55 85.9402 328.45 85.1602 327.15C84.7202 326.41 84.9602 325.46 85.6902 325.02C86.4202 324.58 87.3802 324.82 87.8202 325.55C88.6302 326.9 89.2502 328.02 89.8002 329.01C91.3102 331.72 92.1402 333.22 94.5202 335.43C95.7402 336.56 96.1702 337.68 95.8002 338.76C95.2302 340.45 93.0902 340.88 90.8702 341.1C90.7002 341.12 90.5602 341.13 90.4102 341.13Z" fill="black"/>
  
<path d="M103.08 77.3C102.55 77.3 102.03 77.02 101.74 76.53C101.31 75.79 101.56 74.84 102.3 74.41L104.57 73.09L104.2 62.6L105.24 62.21C105.4 62.15 109.29 60.6 109.79 56.68C110.69 49.65 107.03 39.21 106.99 39.11C106.7 38.3 107.13 37.42 107.93 37.13C108.74 36.84 109.62 37.27 109.91 38.07C110.07 38.53 113.85 49.31 112.86 57.07C112.31 61.4 109.07 63.7 107.37 64.62L107.72 74.84L103.85 77.09C103.61 77.23 103.34 77.3 103.08 77.3Z" fill="black"/>
  
<path d="M76.1496 77.6299C75.6896 77.6299 75.2296 77.4199 74.9196 77.0299C69.6496 70.1899 71.0696 57.3899 79.2696 37.8999C83.2196 26.0899 90.4696 20.9599 100.82 22.6399C107.41 23.7099 111.65 26.4999 113.77 31.1699L114.01 31.6999L113.85 32.2499C112.2 37.8599 106.9 41.9699 100.34 42.7299C96.9396 43.1199 92.4096 42.4999 92.2196 42.4799C91.3696 42.3599 90.7796 41.5799 90.8996 40.7299C91.0196 39.8799 91.7996 39.2899 92.6496 39.4099C92.6896 39.4199 96.9796 39.9999 99.9896 39.6499C105.08 39.0599 109.22 36.0599 110.7 31.9299C108.95 28.5899 105.55 26.5499 100.33 25.6999C91.5696 24.2799 85.6396 28.5999 82.1996 38.9299L82.1596 39.0399C74.6296 56.9299 72.9796 69.4099 77.3796 75.1299C77.8996 75.8099 77.7796 76.7799 77.0996 77.3099C76.8196 77.5299 76.4896 77.6299 76.1496 77.6299Z" fill="black"/>
  
<path d="M120.69 71.9799C120.41 71.9799 120.13 71.8999 119.88 71.7499C119.15 71.2999 118.93 70.3399 119.38 69.6099C120.75 67.3899 124.2 58.1699 110.99 32.5099C110.6 31.7499 110.9 30.8099 111.66 30.4199C112.42 30.0299 113.36 30.3299 113.75 31.0899C126.83 56.5099 124.54 67.1599 122.01 71.2399C121.71 71.7199 121.21 71.9799 120.69 71.9799Z" fill="black"/>
  
<path d="M133.13 155.62L126.55 154.38L85.8502 147.89C83.6002 147.54 79.2602 145.62 79.0302 140.84C78.9602 139.26 77.8002 133.56 76.4602 126.96C74.0602 115.14 71.0702 100.44 70.9402 93.66C70.7402 83.46 75.8702 81.1399 79.6102 79.4499C80.1702 79.1999 80.7002 78.9599 81.1902 78.6999L90.8202 74.1999L90.6802 55.8699C90.6702 55.0099 91.3602 54.2 92.2202 54.2H92.2302C93.0802 54.2 93.7702 54.9899 93.7802 55.8499L93.9302 76.12L82.5502 81.4599C82.0502 81.7199 81.4502 81.9999 80.8802 82.2699C77.2802 83.8999 73.8802 85.4399 74.0302 93.5999C74.1502 100.1 77.2402 115.27 79.4802 126.35C80.9602 133.63 82.0302 138.89 82.1102 140.71C82.2702 144.14 86.1502 144.82 86.3202 144.84L127.06 151.34L132.95 152.45C133.48 152.26 134.64 151.8 136 150.91C136.72 150.44 137.68 150.64 138.15 151.36C138.62 152.08 138.42 153.04 137.7 153.51C135.4 155.02 133.52 155.53 133.45 155.56L133.13 155.62Z" fill="black"/>
  
<path d="M90.8205 58.55C90.7805 58.55 90.7305 58.55 90.6805 58.54C87.2605 58.24 85.0305 56.79 84.0405 54.23C83.4805 52.77 83.5205 51.18 84.1505 49.75C84.7805 48.32 85.9405 47.23 87.4005 46.66C89.1205 46 91.0805 46.19 92.6405 47.18C93.3605 47.64 93.5805 48.6 93.1205 49.32C92.6605 50.04 91.7005 50.26 90.9805 49.8C90.2505 49.34 89.3305 49.24 88.5205 49.56C87.8305 49.82 87.2905 50.34 86.9905 51.01C86.6905 51.68 86.6705 52.43 86.9405 53.11C87.2805 53.99 88.0605 55.18 90.9605 55.44C91.8105 55.52 92.4405 56.27 92.3705 57.12C92.2905 57.95 91.6205 58.55 90.8205 58.55Z" fill="black"/>
  
<path d="M103.41 206.39C102.77 206.39 102.17 205.99 101.95 205.36C101.66 204.55 102.08 203.67 102.89 203.38L111.86 200.18C112.66 199.89 113.55 200.31 113.84 201.12C114.13 201.93 113.71 202.82 112.9 203.1L103.93 206.3C103.76 206.36 103.58 206.39 103.41 206.39Z" fill="black"/>
  
<path d="M88.26 328.01H82.8C81.94 328.01 81.25 327.31 81.25 326.46C81.25 325.6 81.94 324.91 82.8 324.91H85.55C88.06 307.07 103.38 206.47 103.54 205.43C103.67 204.58 104.46 204.04 105.31 204.16C106.16 204.29 106.74 205.1 106.61 205.94C106.45 207.01 90.25 313.12 88.45 326.71L88.26 328.01Z" fill="black"/>
  
<path d="M129.64 328.46C128.82 328.46 128.14 327.82 128.09 327C128.04 326.14 128.69 325.41 129.55 325.36L133.38 325.14C131.57 301.94 132.68 280.39 133.75 259.54C135.07 233.91 136.32 209.71 131.79 186.06C131.63 185.22 132.18 184.41 133.02 184.25C133.87 184.09 134.67 184.64 134.83 185.48C139.43 209.49 138.17 233.88 136.84 259.7C135.75 280.92 134.62 302.87 136.59 326.47L136.72 328.06L129.72 328.47C129.7 328.46 129.67 328.46 129.64 328.46Z" fill="black"/>
  
<path d="M107.39 106.94C106.55 106.94 105.86 106.24 105.84 105.39L105.6 95.08L90.5897 77.08C90.0397 76.42 90.1297 75.44 90.7897 74.89C91.4497 74.34 92.4197 74.43 92.9697 75.09L108.33 93.5C108.55 93.77 108.68 94.11 108.69 94.46L108.95 105.33C108.97 106.19 108.29 106.95 107.44 106.95C107.42 106.94 107.41 106.94 107.39 106.94Z" fill="black"/>
  
<path d="M140.8 104.05C140.61 104.05 140.42 104.01 140.23 103.94C139.49 103.65 139.19 103.33 132.74 93.82C129.4 88.9 124.44 81.57 123.09 80.21C118.66 79.49 114.57 78.53 112.52 78.02L108.65 94.83C108.46 95.67 107.62 96.19 106.79 95.99C105.96 95.8 105.43 94.97 105.63 94.13L109.9 75.6C110.04 75 110.51 74.54 111.12 74.43C111.61 74.33 112.11 74.48 112.46 74.81C113.98 75.2 118.82 76.4 123.94 77.21C125.09 77.39 125.78 78.02 135.32 92.09C137.99 96.03 141.02 100.49 141.72 101.25C142.28 101.66 142.52 102.4 142.26 103.08C142 103.68 141.41 104.05 140.8 104.05Z" fill="black"/>
  
<path d="M129.33 124.16C129.31 124.16 129.29 124.16 129.27 124.16C128.41 124.13 127.74 123.41 127.78 122.55L128.44 103.94C128.47 103.08 129.18 102.41 130.05 102.44C130.91 102.47 131.58 103.19 131.54 104.05L130.88 122.66C130.85 123.5 130.16 124.16 129.33 124.16Z" fill="black"/>
  
</g>
<g clip-path="url(#clip2)">
<path d="M417.05 136.93L406.78 126.66L417.05 116.39L427.33 126.66L417.05 136.93ZM410.06 126.65L417.04 133.63L424.02 126.65L417.04 119.67L410.06 126.65Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M427.16 254.91C427.16 256.55 425.83 257.88 424.19 257.88C422.55 257.88 421.21 256.55 421.21 254.91C421.21 253.27 422.54 251.93 424.19 251.93C425.83 251.93 427.16 253.27 427.16 254.91Z" fill="black"/>
  
<path d="M397.14 163.18C397.14 164.76 395.85 166.05 394.27 166.05C392.68 166.05 391.4 164.77 391.4 163.18C391.4 161.59 392.69 160.31 394.27 160.31C395.86 160.31 397.14 161.59 397.14 163.18Z" fill="black"/>
  
<path d="M445.01 223.39H412.43C411.57 223.39 410.88 222.69 410.88 221.84C410.88 220.98 411.57 220.29 412.43 220.29H445.01C445.87 220.29 446.56 220.99 446.56 221.84C446.57 222.7 445.87 223.39 445.01 223.39Z" fill="black"/>
  
<path d="M414.76 202.45H398.47C397.61 202.45 396.92 201.75 396.92 200.9C396.92 200.04 397.62 199.35 398.47 199.35H414.76C415.62 199.35 416.31 200.05 416.31 200.9C416.32 201.75 415.62 202.45 414.76 202.45Z" fill="black"/>
  
<path d="M324.28 132.36C324.2 132.36 324.12 132.35 324.04 132.34C323.19 132.21 322.61 131.42 322.74 130.57C322.99 128.96 328.82 91.2601 330.7 82.6901C330.63 81.3901 330.31 79.5001 330.09 78.2201C329.95 77.3701 330.52 76.5701 331.36 76.4301C332.21 76.2901 333.01 76.8601 333.15 77.7001C333.39 79.1201 333.75 81.2601 333.81 82.7501L333.82 82.9501L333.77 83.1501C331.97 91.2001 325.86 130.64 325.8 131.04C325.69 131.81 325.03 132.36 324.28 132.36Z" fill="black"/>
  
<path d="M335.99 129.36C335.96 129.36 335.92 129.36 335.89 129.36C335.04 129.31 334.39 128.57 334.44 127.71C334.46 127.37 336.66 93.1402 336.43 84.4802L336.42 84.2102L338.12 78.9702C338.38 78.1602 339.26 77.7102 340.07 77.9702C340.89 78.2302 341.33 79.1102 341.07 79.9202L339.53 84.6502C339.72 93.8402 337.62 126.5 337.53 127.89C337.49 128.73 336.8 129.36 335.99 129.36Z" fill="black"/>
  
<path d="M370.19 184.08C369.38 184.08 368.7 183.45 368.64 182.63L366.65 150.72C366.6 149.87 367.25 149.13 368.1 149.07C368.96 149.03 369.69 149.67 369.74 150.52L371.74 182.43C371.79 183.28 371.14 184.02 370.29 184.07C370.25 184.08 370.22 184.08 370.19 184.08Z" fill="black"/>
  
<path d="M300.9 159.76C296.45 159.76 295.33 157.53 294.53 154.85C294.34 154.23 294.17 153.64 293.91 153.14C293.51 152.39 293.79 151.44 294.55 151.04C295.31 150.63 296.25 150.92 296.65 151.68C297.06 152.45 297.3 153.25 297.51 153.96C298.17 156.17 298.6 157.62 305.56 156C316.79 153.38 336.61 149.13 351.09 146.02C355.22 145.13 358.82 144.36 361.5 143.78C363.1 138.06 365.38 130.97 367.77 123.5C370.89 113.75 374.12 103.68 375.84 96.64C377.3 82.8 367.62 78.46 358.26 74.27L357.8 74.06C357.02 73.71 356.67 72.79 357.02 72.01C357.37 71.23 358.29 70.88 359.07 71.23L359.53 71.44C368.95 75.66 380.67 80.91 378.92 97.08C378.91 97.15 378.9 97.21 378.88 97.28C377.15 104.43 373.88 114.61 370.73 124.45C368.21 132.3 365.84 139.71 364.24 145.52C364.09 146.08 363.64 146.5 363.07 146.63C360.32 147.23 356.36 148.08 351.73 149.07C338.08 152 317.46 156.42 306.25 159.04C304.08 159.53 302.32 159.75 300.9 159.76Z" fill="black"/>
  
<path d="M304.58 87.15C304.25 87.15 303.92 87.05 303.64 86.83C302.96 86.31 302.83 85.34 303.35 84.66L311 74.69C311.19 74.45 311.44 74.27 311.72 74.17L329 68.19C329.81 67.91 330.69 68.34 330.97 69.15C331.25 69.96 330.82 70.84 330.01 71.12L313.17 76.95L305.81 86.55C305.51 86.95 305.05 87.15 304.58 87.15Z" fill="black"/>
  
<path d="M318.01 341.3H292.45L292.17 341.19C290.88 340.67 289.94 339.32 289.67 337.59C289.37 335.71 289.86 333.03 292.11 331.16C293.54 329.97 293.98 329.67 296.37 328.44C300.16 290 307.74 172.74 307.82 171.55C307.87 170.7 308.61 170.05 309.47 170.1C310.32 170.15 310.97 170.89 310.92 171.75C310.84 172.95 303.14 292 299.38 329.58L299.3 330.42L298.55 330.81C295.54 332.35 295.4 332.46 294.11 333.54C292.85 334.59 292.58 336.07 292.74 337.11C292.82 337.65 293.02 338.02 293.19 338.2H315.35C317.17 326.3 330.73 237.04 334.5 195.32L334.65 193.67L336.28 193.92C336.51 193.96 337.11 194.02 337.79 194.09C338.71 194.19 339.74 194.3 340.26 194.38L341.41 194.56L341.56 195.72C345.89 228.94 352.54 297.48 355.46 329.08L355.55 330.04L354.73 330.54C353.79 331.12 353.01 331.55 352.32 331.93C351.56 332.35 350.9 332.71 350.25 333.15C348.9 334.07 347.88 336.36 347.91 337.2C350.79 337.57 364.42 337.28 371.14 337.1L366.64 191.56C366.61 190.7 367.29 189.99 368.14 189.96C368.97 189.93 369.71 190.61 369.74 191.46L374.33 340.11L372.78 340.16C371.9 340.19 351.09 340.81 347.36 340.26C346.17 340.14 345.23 339.34 344.93 338.14C344.32 335.73 346.38 332.04 348.5 330.59C349.28 330.05 350.04 329.64 350.84 329.2C351.3 328.95 351.77 328.69 352.29 328.39C349.37 296.78 342.93 230.56 338.65 197.31C338.26 197.27 337.84 197.22 337.47 197.18C337.46 197.18 337.46 197.18 337.45 197.18C333.2 242.51 318.36 339 318.21 339.98L318.01 341.3Z" fill="black"/>
  
<path d="M340.8 76.2C335.52 76.2 330.78 72.39 330.53 72.18L329.92 71.68L329.96 70.89C329.96 70.85 330.18 66.81 329.99 62.23C326.01 58.58 323.77 53.29 323.32 46.48C322.23 30.16 324.25 25.82 324.48 25.38C324.88 24.62 325.82 24.33 326.58 24.73C327.34 25.13 327.62 26.07 327.22 26.83C327.22 26.83 325.39 30.94 326.41 46.27C326.83 52.5 328.88 57.22 332.51 60.31L333.02 60.74L333.05 61.41C333.24 65.2 333.15 68.66 333.09 70.2C334.82 71.41 339.95 74.53 344.04 72.26C344.79 71.84 345.73 72.11 346.15 72.86C346.57 73.61 346.3 74.55 345.55 74.97C343.99 75.86 342.37 76.2 340.8 76.2Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M356.44 37.6301C356.36 37.6301 356.28 37.6201 356.2 37.6101C355.35 37.4801 354.78 36.6801 354.91 35.8401C354.92 35.7801 355.77 29.9201 352.75 23.5201C350.55 19.9301 344.93 16.7801 335.68 18.6501C331.75 19.4401 328.24 23.0001 327.16 27.2001C328.92 30.7401 334.68 31.0301 341.98 31.0301C347.36 31.0301 348.93 34.2801 349.01 36.0001C349.05 36.8601 348.39 37.5801 347.53 37.6201C346.68 37.6701 345.95 37.0001 345.91 36.1401C345.89 35.9701 345.6 34.1301 341.97 34.1301C335.06 34.1301 326.46 34.1301 324.07 27.9001L323.91 27.4701L324.01 27.0201C325.2 21.3701 329.74 16.6701 335.06 15.6001C345.95 13.4001 352.73 17.4501 355.44 21.9701L355.51 22.1001C359 29.4301 358.01 36.0301 357.97 36.3001C357.84 37.0901 357.19 37.6301 356.44 37.6301Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M340.03 197.19C339.94 197.19 339.85 197.18 339.75 197.17L331.56 195.7C330.72 195.55 330.15 194.74 330.31 193.9C330.46 193.06 331.26 192.49 332.11 192.65L340.3 194.12C341.14 194.27 341.7 195.08 341.55 195.92C341.42 196.67 340.76 197.19 340.03 197.19Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M359.76 74.86C359.48 74.86 359.19 74.78 358.93 74.62L351.95 70.21L350.75 51.39C350.7 50.53 351.35 49.8 352.2 49.74C353.04 49.69 353.79 50.33 353.85 51.19L354.95 68.43L360.59 72C361.31 72.46 361.53 73.42 361.07 74.14C360.77 74.6 360.27 74.86 359.76 74.86Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M351.02 52.2602C350.25 52.2602 349.58 51.6902 349.48 50.9002C349.37 50.0502 349.97 49.2702 350.83 49.1702C354.02 48.7702 354.77 47.4002 355.06 46.4102C355.55 44.7302 354.54 42.8802 352.81 42.3002C351.83 41.9702 350.81 42.1002 350.01 42.6702C349.31 43.1702 348.34 43.0002 347.85 42.3002C347.35 41.6002 347.52 40.6302 348.22 40.1402C349.81 39.0102 351.9 38.7202 353.81 39.3602C357.1 40.4702 359 44.0302 358.04 47.2802C357.47 49.2202 355.83 51.6602 351.22 52.2402C351.15 52.2502 351.08 52.2602 351.02 52.2602Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M369.77 185.38H355.03C354.17 185.38 353.48 184.68 353.48 183.83C353.48 182.97 354.17 182.28 355.03 182.28H369.77C370.63 182.28 371.32 182.98 371.32 183.83C371.33 184.69 370.63 185.38 369.77 185.38Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M309.57 143.44C309.28 143.44 308.98 143.36 308.73 143.19L299.76 137.42C299.04 136.96 298.83 136 299.29 135.28C299.75 134.56 300.71 134.35 301.43 134.81L309.84 140.21L347.87 130.51L357.26 97.14C357.49 96.32 358.35 95.84 359.17 96.07C360 96.3 360.47 97.16 360.24 97.98L350.6 132.21C350.45 132.74 350.03 133.16 349.49 133.29L309.94 143.38C309.83 143.42 309.7 143.44 309.57 143.44Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M293.62 149.47C293.01 149.47 292.43 149.11 292.18 148.51C291.86 147.72 292.24 146.81 293.03 146.49L300.34 143.5C301.13 143.18 302.04 143.56 302.36 144.35C302.69 145.14 302.3 146.05 301.51 146.37L294.2 149.36C294.01 149.43 293.81 149.47 293.62 149.47Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M314.02 157.16C313.37 157.16 312.76 156.75 312.55 156.1L309.89 148.12C309.62 147.31 310.06 146.43 310.87 146.16C311.69 145.89 312.56 146.33 312.83 147.14L315.49 155.12C315.76 155.93 315.32 156.81 314.51 157.08C314.35 157.14 314.18 157.16 314.02 157.16Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M334.98 63.53C332.78 63.53 331.16 63.02 331.03 62.98C330.21 62.72 329.77 61.84 330.03 61.03C330.29 60.22 331.16 59.76 331.98 60.03C332.01 60.04 336.05 61.27 339.36 59.34C340.1 58.91 341.05 59.16 341.48 59.9C341.91 60.64 341.66 61.59 340.92 62.02C338.9 63.2 336.75 63.53 334.98 63.53Z" fill="black"/>
  
<path id="lamp2" d="M223.57 212.53C223.16 212.53 222.77 212.47 222.48 212.19C222.19 211.9 222.02 211.56 222.02 211.15L221.49 126.35C221.49 126.16 221.52 125.98 221.6 125.8C222.7 122.96 225.38 121.26 228.77 121.26C230.17 121.26 231.62 121.56 232.97 122.12C233.68 122.42 234.54 122.84 235.52 123.34C238.32 124.73 242.14 126.64 244.99 126.65C252.57 126.65 258.72 120.51 258.75 112.97C258.76 109.31 257.34 105.86 254.76 103.26C252.18 100.66 248.74 99.2301 245.08 99.2201C241.92 99.2201 237.74 101.42 234.7 103.03C233.69 103.56 232.82 104.02 232.1 104.34C230.97 104.85 229.78 105.1 228.55 105.1C225.46 105.1 222.75 103.48 221.48 100.88C221.38 100.67 221.33 100.44 221.32 100.21L221 46.8001C221 46.3801 221.16 45.9801 221.46 45.6801C221.76 45.3901 222.17 45.2201 222.58 45.2401C238.21 45.6001 256.2 47.4501 271.18 58.4501C287.27 70.2601 295.7 85.1501 296.94 103.97C297.83 117.42 293.58 138.48 268.28 162.41C267.74 162.92 267.27 163.37 267.13 163.53C252.19 180.36 251.3 210.76 251.29 211.06C251.27 211.9 250.59 212.46 249.75 212.47L223.57 212.53C223.58 212.53 223.57 212.53 223.57 212.53Z" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="3"/>
  
<path d="M226.57 225.72C225.72 225.72 225.02 224.88 225.02 224.02C225.01 223.16 225.7 222.22 226.56 222.21L247.47 221.83H247.48C248.33 221.83 249.03 222.69 249.03 223.54C249.04 224.4 248.35 225.33 247.49 225.34L226.57 225.72C226.58 225.72 226.57 225.72 226.57 225.72Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M227.13 239.68C226.28 239.68 225.58 238.97 225.58 238.12C225.57 237.26 226.27 236.62 227.12 236.62L242.9 236.58H242.91C243.76 236.58 244.46 237.2 244.46 238.06C244.47 238.92 243.77 239.6 242.92 239.6L227.13 239.68Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M312.36 130.31C311.51 130.31 310.82 129.59 310.81 128.74L310.48 98.6802C310.47 97.8202 311.16 96.9602 312.02 96.9602C312.02 96.9602 312.03 96.9602 312.04 96.9602C312.89 96.9602 313.58 97.7802 313.59 98.6302L313.92 128.65C313.93 129.51 313.24 130.32 312.39 130.32C312.37 130.31 312.36 130.31 312.36 130.31Z" fill="black"/>
</g>
<defs>
<clipPath id="clip0">
<rect y="75" width="460.76" height="266.82" fill="white"/>
</clipPath>
<clipPath id="clip1">
<rect x="70" width="207.82" height="341.13" fill="white"/>
</clipPath>
<clipPath id="clip2">
<rect x="221" y="15" width="225.57" height="326.3" fill="white"/>
</clipPath>
</defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: А можно сделать так чтобы не контуром а сплошной линией прорисовывалось?

Comment: @Сергей добавил с единичной обнодкой

Comment: Если с единичной обводкой то получается контур, а сплошной линией нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Вот как получилось:

```css
#lamp1,
#lamp2 {

  fill: none; /*Заливка элемента*/
  stroke: black; /*Цвет обводки*/
  stroke-width: 1; /*Толщина обводки*/
  stroke-dashoffset: 967; /*Смещение пунктирной обводки относительно первоначального положения*/
  stroke-dasharray: 0 0 967;  
  animation: draw 10s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes draw {
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 0 967;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dasharray: 967 0 967;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg width="461" height="342" viewBox="0 0 461 342" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<g clip-path="url(#clip0)">
<path d="M261.34 150.95C261.34 192.89 227.34 226.9 185.39 226.9C143.44 226.9 109.44 192.9 109.44 150.95C109.45 109 143.45 75 185.4 75C227.34 75 261.34 109 261.34 150.95Z" fill="#F3EC18"/>
<path d="M459.2 341.82H1.55C0.69 341.82 0 341.12 0 340.27C0 339.41 0.7 338.72 1.55 338.72H459.2C460.06 338.72 460.75 339.42 460.75 340.27C460.76 341.12 460.06 341.82 459.2 341.82Z" fill="black"/>
</g>
<g clip-path="url(#clip1)">
<path d="M123.85 153.28C123.78 153.28 123.71 153.28 123.64 153.27C122.79 153.15 122.2 152.37 122.32 151.52L122.82 147.91C122.94 147.06 123.72 146.47 124.57 146.58C125.42 146.7 126.01 147.48 125.9 148.33L125.4 151.94C125.28 152.72 124.61 153.28 123.85 153.28Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M123.75 143.44C123.62 143.44 123.48 143.42 123.36 143.39L93.0396 135.41C92.4596 135.26 92.0196 134.78 91.9096 134.19L85.9296 101.62C85.7696 100.78 86.3296 99.97 87.1796 99.81C88.0296 99.66 88.8296 100.21 88.9896 101.06L94.7896 132.66L123.57 140.23L127.66 138.09C128.42 137.69 129.36 137.99 129.76 138.75C130.16 139.51 129.86 140.45 129.1 140.84L124.48 143.26C124.25 143.38 124 143.44 123.75 143.44Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M215.62 17.01C214.76 17.01 214.07 16.32 214.07 15.46V1.55C214.07 0.69 214.77 0 215.62 0C216.48 0 217.17 0.69 217.17 1.55V15.46C217.18 16.32 216.48 17.01 215.62 17.01Z" fill="#1A1A1A"/>
<path d="M164.41 38.6901C164.01 38.6901 163.62 38.5401 163.31 38.2401L154.88 29.8101C154.27 29.2001 154.27 28.2201 154.88 27.6201C155.49 27.0101 156.47 27.0101 157.07 27.6201L165.5 36.0501C166.11 36.6601 166.11 37.6401 165.5 38.2401C165.2 38.5401 164.81 38.6901 164.41 38.6901Z" fill="#1A1A1A"/>
<path d="M268.141 36.6901C267.741 36.6901 267.351 36.5401 267.041 36.2401C266.431 35.6301 266.431 34.6501 267.041 34.0501L275.171 25.9201C275.781 25.3201 276.761 25.3101 277.361 25.9201C277.971 26.5301 277.971 27.5101 277.361 28.1101L269.231 36.2401C268.931 36.5401 268.531 36.6901 268.141 36.6901Z" fill="#1A1A1A"/>
<path id="lamp1" d="M189.89 234.13C189.08 234.13 188.4 233.5 188.35 232.68C188.33 232.34 185.81 198.72 166 182.55C152.11 171.2 142.91 152.89 142 134.76C141.11 116.97 146.48 100.14 157.13 87.39C168.01 74.36 183.58 66.7 200.97 65.83C201.27 65.81 201.57 65.8 201.92 65.79L202.3 65.78C203.16 65.74 203.87 66.4 203.91 67.25L206.19 112.79C206.19 112.84 206.19 112.89 206.19 112.93C206.12 114.64 206.66 116.19 207.73 117.3C209.15 118.78 211.34 119.23 213.11 118.35C214.1 117.86 215.16 117.01 216.38 116.02C219.46 113.54 223.29 110.45 229.55 110.14C229.85 110.12 230.15 110.12 230.45 110.12C239.85 110.12 247.01 117.05 247.85 126.97C248.41 133.6 245.83 137.91 243.57 140.37C240.44 143.77 235.97 145.72 231.31 145.72C230.91 145.72 230.5 145.72 230.1 145.68C225.49 145.34 220.93 143.44 217.27 141.91C216.29 141.5 215.37 141.12 214.58 140.82C212.82 140.16 210.95 140.61 209.6 141.98C208.48 143.12 207.84 144.75 207.87 146.45L212.13 231.46C212.15 231.87 212.01 232.27 211.73 232.58C211.45 232.88 211.07 233.07 210.66 233.09L189.98 234.13C189.95 234.13 189.92 234.13 189.89 234.13ZM200.89 68.9401C167.29 70.7501 143.32 98.94 145.1 134.61C145.97 151.89 154.72 169.34 167.96 180.15C186.58 195.36 190.59 223.97 191.31 230.95L208.96 230.07L204.78 146.56C204.74 143.98 205.69 141.54 207.4 139.81C209.6 137.58 212.78 136.84 215.68 137.93C216.52 138.25 217.48 138.64 218.48 139.06C221.94 140.5 226.24 142.3 230.35 142.61C230.68 142.63 231 142.65 231.33 142.65C235.12 142.65 238.76 141.06 241.3 138.3C243.14 136.3 245.24 132.75 244.77 127.25C244.07 119 238.19 113.24 230.47 113.24C230.22 113.24 229.97 113.25 229.72 113.26C224.46 113.52 221.21 116.15 218.34 118.46C217.03 119.52 215.79 120.52 214.49 121.16C213.44 121.68 212.32 121.94 211.16 121.94C209.06 121.94 206.99 121.04 205.49 119.47C203.85 117.76 203 115.43 203.09 112.9L200.89 68.9401Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M193.64 247.17C192.82 247.17 192.13 246.53 192.09 245.7C192.05 244.84 192.71 244.12 193.56 244.07L212 243.15C212.84 243.12 213.59 243.77 213.63 244.62C213.67 245.48 213.01 246.2 212.16 246.25L193.71 247.17C193.7 247.16 193.67 247.17 193.64 247.17Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M201.06 260.79C200.24 260.79 199.55 260.15 199.51 259.32C199.47 258.46 200.13 257.73 200.98 257.69L212.19 257.13C213.04 257.09 213.77 257.75 213.81 258.6C213.85 259.46 213.19 260.18 212.34 260.23L201.13 260.79C201.11 260.79 201.09 260.79 201.06 260.79Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M106.82 186.06C106.02 186.06 105.34 185.29 105.28 184.49L104.54 175.32C104.47 174.46 105.11 173.68 105.96 173.61C106.83 173.54 107.56 174.16 107.63 175.01L108.25 182.6C112.62 182.35 125.63 181.31 132.81 177.47C131.19 173.09 129.87 166.75 129.81 166.46C129.64 165.62 130.17 164.8 131.01 164.63C131.84 164.45 132.67 164.99 132.84 165.83C132.86 165.91 134.45 173.53 136.17 177.53C136.47 178.23 136.22 179.19 135.58 179.6C126.64 185.28 107.68 186.06 106.87 186.06C106.85 186.06 106.84 186.06 106.82 186.06Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M101.35 185.96C90.2696 185.96 75.4196 182.43 74.7996 182.28C74.0496 182.1 73.5396 181.39 73.6196 180.62C73.6996 179.86 75.4596 161.89 76.4596 155.6C76.5896 154.75 77.3996 154.18 78.2296 154.31C79.0796 154.44 79.6496 155.24 79.5196 156.08C78.6996 161.29 77.2796 175.15 76.8396 179.56C80.7396 180.42 92.4996 182.85 101.35 182.85C102.21 182.85 102.9 183.55 102.9 184.4C102.9 185.26 102.2 185.96 101.35 185.96Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M120.93 328.14C120.16 328.14 119.49 327.56 119.39 326.77C118.54 319.71 117.56 313.73 116.43 306.81C113.65 289.8 109.85 266.5 104.53 206.05C104.45 205.2 105.09 204.44 105.94 204.37C106.8 204.29 107.55 204.93 107.62 205.78C112.92 266.12 116.72 289.35 119.49 306.32C120.62 313.28 121.61 319.28 122.47 326.41C122.57 327.26 121.97 328.03 121.12 328.14C121.05 328.14 120.99 328.14 120.93 328.14Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M73.83 327.86C73.01 327.86 72.32 327.21 72.28 326.38C71.89 318.52 71.73 309.06 71.53 297.08C71.39 288.56 71.23 278.91 70.95 268.01C70.83 263.39 70.67 259.01 70.51 254.77C69.74 233.88 69.07 215.83 74.65 188.98C74.82 188.14 75.65 187.6 76.48 187.78C77.32 187.95 77.86 188.78 77.68 189.61C72.18 216.09 72.84 233.96 73.61 254.66C73.77 258.9 73.93 263.29 74.05 267.93C74.33 278.84 74.49 288.51 74.64 297.03C74.84 308.98 75 318.41 75.38 326.23C75.42 327.09 74.76 327.81 73.91 327.86C73.88 327.85 73.85 327.86 73.83 327.86Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M139.26 341.13C137.61 341.13 135.42 339.94 131.39 337.74C130.78 337.41 130.14 337.06 129.46 336.69C129.22 338.02 129.13 338.78 129.13 339.56C129.13 340.39 128.47 341.08 127.64 341.11C127.36 341.12 123.9 341.11 122.84 341.11C122.01 341.11 121.33 340.45 121.29 339.62L120.79 327.16C120.76 326.3 121.42 325.58 122.28 325.55C123.17 325.52 123.86 326.18 123.89 327.04L124.33 338.02C124.95 338.02 125.58 338.02 126.12 338.02C126.23 337.06 126.45 335.89 126.8 334.04C126.89 333.56 127.21 333.15 127.65 332.93C128.09 332.72 128.61 332.73 129.04 332.96C130.45 333.71 131.72 334.4 132.86 335.02C135.66 336.55 138.57 338.14 139.32 338.03C140.26 337.94 140.86 337.83 141.24 337.73C141.23 337.72 141.23 337.72 141.22 337.71C138.48 335.16 137.45 333.32 135.9 330.53C135.36 329.56 134.75 328.46 133.97 327.16C133.53 326.42 133.77 325.47 134.5 325.03C135.23 324.59 136.19 324.83 136.63 325.56C137.44 326.91 138.06 328.03 138.61 329.02C140.12 331.73 140.95 333.23 143.33 335.44C144.55 336.57 144.98 337.69 144.61 338.77C144.04 340.46 141.9 340.89 139.68 341.11C139.56 341.12 139.41 341.13 139.26 341.13Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M90.4102 341.13C88.7602 341.13 86.5702 339.93 82.5402 337.74C81.9402 337.41 81.4802 337.06 80.8002 336.69C80.5502 338.08 80.6602 338.8 80.6602 339.56V341.05L78.9802 341.11C78.7002 341.12 75.1402 341.11 74.0902 341.11H72.5602L71.9802 327.16C71.9402 326.3 72.6002 325.58 73.4602 325.55C74.3502 325.52 75.0302 326.18 75.0702 327.04L75.5102 338.02C76.1302 338.02 76.7602 338.02 77.3002 338.02C77.4102 337.06 77.6302 335.89 77.9802 334.04L78.3802 331.98L80.2302 332.96C81.6402 333.71 82.9102 334.4 84.0502 335.02C86.8502 336.55 89.7402 338.13 90.5102 338.03C91.4502 337.94 92.0502 337.83 92.4302 337.73C92.4202 337.72 92.4202 337.72 92.4102 337.71C89.6702 335.16 88.6402 333.32 87.0902 330.52C86.5502 329.55 85.9402 328.45 85.1602 327.15C84.7202 326.41 84.9602 325.46 85.6902 325.02C86.4202 324.58 87.3802 324.82 87.8202 325.55C88.6302 326.9 89.2502 328.02 89.8002 329.01C91.3102 331.72 92.1402 333.22 94.5202 335.43C95.7402 336.56 96.1702 337.68 95.8002 338.76C95.2302 340.45 93.0902 340.88 90.8702 341.1C90.7002 341.12 90.5602 341.13 90.4102 341.13Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M103.08 77.3C102.55 77.3 102.03 77.02 101.74 76.53C101.31 75.79 101.56 74.84 102.3 74.41L104.57 73.09L104.2 62.6L105.24 62.21C105.4 62.15 109.29 60.6 109.79 56.68C110.69 49.65 107.03 39.21 106.99 39.11C106.7 38.3 107.13 37.42 107.93 37.13C108.74 36.84 109.62 37.27 109.91 38.07C110.07 38.53 113.85 49.31 112.86 57.07C112.31 61.4 109.07 63.7 107.37 64.62L107.72 74.84L103.85 77.09C103.61 77.23 103.34 77.3 103.08 77.3Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M76.1496 77.6299C75.6896 77.6299 75.2296 77.4199 74.9196 77.0299C69.6496 70.1899 71.0696 57.3899 79.2696 37.8999C83.2196 26.0899 90.4696 20.9599 100.82 22.6399C107.41 23.7099 111.65 26.4999 113.77 31.1699L114.01 31.6999L113.85 32.2499C112.2 37.8599 106.9 41.9699 100.34 42.7299C96.9396 43.1199 92.4096 42.4999 92.2196 42.4799C91.3696 42.3599 90.7796 41.5799 90.8996 40.7299C91.0196 39.8799 91.7996 39.2899 92.6496 39.4099C92.6896 39.4199 96.9796 39.9999 99.9896 39.6499C105.08 39.0599 109.22 36.0599 110.7 31.9299C108.95 28.5899 105.55 26.5499 100.33 25.6999C91.5696 24.2799 85.6396 28.5999 82.1996 38.9299L82.1596 39.0399C74.6296 56.9299 72.9796 69.4099 77.3796 75.1299C77.8996 75.8099 77.7796 76.7799 77.0996 77.3099C76.8196 77.5299 76.4896 77.6299 76.1496 77.6299Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M120.69 71.9799C120.41 71.9799 120.13 71.8999 119.88 71.7499C119.15 71.2999 118.93 70.3399 119.38 69.6099C120.75 67.3899 124.2 58.1699 110.99 32.5099C110.6 31.7499 110.9 30.8099 111.66 30.4199C112.42 30.0299 113.36 30.3299 113.75 31.0899C126.83 56.5099 124.54 67.1599 122.01 71.2399C121.71 71.7199 121.21 71.9799 120.69 71.9799Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M133.13 155.62L126.55 154.38L85.8502 147.89C83.6002 147.54 79.2602 145.62 79.0302 140.84C78.9602 139.26 77.8002 133.56 76.4602 126.96C74.0602 115.14 71.0702 100.44 70.9402 93.66C70.7402 83.46 75.8702 81.1399 79.6102 79.4499C80.1702 79.1999 80.7002 78.9599 81.1902 78.6999L90.8202 74.1999L90.6802 55.8699C90.6702 55.0099 91.3602 54.2 92.2202 54.2H92.2302C93.0802 54.2 93.7702 54.9899 93.7802 55.8499L93.9302 76.12L82.5502 81.4599C82.0502 81.7199 81.4502 81.9999 80.8802 82.2699C77.2802 83.8999 73.8802 85.4399 74.0302 93.5999C74.1502 100.1 77.2402 115.27 79.4802 126.35C80.9602 133.63 82.0302 138.89 82.1102 140.71C82.2702 144.14 86.1502 144.82 86.3202 144.84L127.06 151.34L132.95 152.45C133.48 152.26 134.64 151.8 136 150.91C136.72 150.44 137.68 150.64 138.15 151.36C138.62 152.08 138.42 153.04 137.7 153.51C135.4 155.02 133.52 155.53 133.45 155.56L133.13 155.62Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M90.8205 58.55C90.7805 58.55 90.7305 58.55 90.6805 58.54C87.2605 58.24 85.0305 56.79 84.0405 54.23C83.4805 52.77 83.5205 51.18 84.1505 49.75C84.7805 48.32 85.9405 47.23 87.4005 46.66C89.1205 46 91.0805 46.19 92.6405 47.18C93.3605 47.64 93.5805 48.6 93.1205 49.32C92.6605 50.04 91.7005 50.26 90.9805 49.8C90.2505 49.34 89.3305 49.24 88.5205 49.56C87.8305 49.82 87.2905 50.34 86.9905 51.01C86.6905 51.68 86.6705 52.43 86.9405 53.11C87.2805 53.99 88.0605 55.18 90.9605 55.44C91.8105 55.52 92.4405 56.27 92.3705 57.12C92.2905 57.95 91.6205 58.55 90.8205 58.55Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M103.41 206.39C102.77 206.39 102.17 205.99 101.95 205.36C101.66 204.55 102.08 203.67 102.89 203.38L111.86 200.18C112.66 199.89 113.55 200.31 113.84 201.12C114.13 201.93 113.71 202.82 112.9 203.1L103.93 206.3C103.76 206.36 103.58 206.39 103.41 206.39Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M88.26 328.01H82.8C81.94 328.01 81.25 327.31 81.25 326.46C81.25 325.6 81.94 324.91 82.8 324.91H85.55C88.06 307.07 103.38 206.47 103.54 205.43C103.67 204.58 104.46 204.04 105.31 204.16C106.16 204.29 106.74 205.1 106.61 205.94C106.45 207.01 90.25 313.12 88.45 326.71L88.26 328.01Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M129.64 328.46C128.82 328.46 128.14 327.82 128.09 327C128.04 326.14 128.69 325.41 129.55 325.36L133.38 325.14C131.57 301.94 132.68 280.39 133.75 259.54C135.07 233.91 136.32 209.71 131.79 186.06C131.63 185.22 132.18 184.41 133.02 184.25C133.87 184.09 134.67 184.64 134.83 185.48C139.43 209.49 138.17 233.88 136.84 259.7C135.75 280.92 134.62 302.87 136.59 326.47L136.72 328.06L129.72 328.47C129.7 328.46 129.67 328.46 129.64 328.46Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M107.39 106.94C106.55 106.94 105.86 106.24 105.84 105.39L105.6 95.08L90.5897 77.08C90.0397 76.42 90.1297 75.44 90.7897 74.89C91.4497 74.34 92.4197 74.43 92.9697 75.09L108.33 93.5C108.55 93.77 108.68 94.11 108.69 94.46L108.95 105.33C108.97 106.19 108.29 106.95 107.44 106.95C107.42 106.94 107.41 106.94 107.39 106.94Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M140.8 104.05C140.61 104.05 140.42 104.01 140.23 103.94C139.49 103.65 139.19 103.33 132.74 93.82C129.4 88.9 124.44 81.57 123.09 80.21C118.66 79.49 114.57 78.53 112.52 78.02L108.65 94.83C108.46 95.67 107.62 96.19 106.79 95.99C105.96 95.8 105.43 94.97 105.63 94.13L109.9 75.6C110.04 75 110.51 74.54 111.12 74.43C111.61 74.33 112.11 74.48 112.46 74.81C113.98 75.2 118.82 76.4 123.94 77.21C125.09 77.39 125.78 78.02 135.32 92.09C137.99 96.03 141.02 100.49 141.72 101.25C142.28 101.66 142.52 102.4 142.26 103.08C142 103.68 141.41 104.05 140.8 104.05Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M129.33 124.16C129.31 124.16 129.29 124.16 129.27 124.16C128.41 124.13 127.74 123.41 127.78 122.55L128.44 103.94C128.47 103.08 129.18 102.41 130.05 102.44C130.91 102.47 131.58 103.19 131.54 104.05L130.88 122.66C130.85 123.5 130.16 124.16 129.33 124.16Z" fill="black"/>
</g>
<g clip-path="url(#clip2)">
<path d="M417.05 136.93L406.78 126.66L417.05 116.39L427.33 126.66L417.05 136.93ZM410.06 126.65L417.04 133.63L424.02 126.65L417.04 119.67L410.06 126.65Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M427.16 254.91C427.16 256.55 425.83 257.88 424.19 257.88C422.55 257.88 421.21 256.55 421.21 254.91C421.21 253.27 422.54 251.93 424.19 251.93C425.83 251.93 427.16 253.27 427.16 254.91Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M397.14 163.18C397.14 164.76 395.85 166.05 394.27 166.05C392.68 166.05 391.4 164.77 391.4 163.18C391.4 161.59 392.69 160.31 394.27 160.31C395.86 160.31 397.14 161.59 397.14 163.18Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M445.01 223.39H412.43C411.57 223.39 410.88 222.69 410.88 221.84C410.88 220.98 411.57 220.29 412.43 220.29H445.01C445.87 220.29 446.56 220.99 446.56 221.84C446.57 222.7 445.87 223.39 445.01 223.39Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M414.76 202.45H398.47C397.61 202.45 396.92 201.75 396.92 200.9C396.92 200.04 397.62 199.35 398.47 199.35H414.76C415.62 199.35 416.31 200.05 416.31 200.9C416.32 201.75 415.62 202.45 414.76 202.45Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M324.28 132.36C324.2 132.36 324.12 132.35 324.04 132.34C323.19 132.21 322.61 131.42 322.74 130.57C322.99 128.96 328.82 91.2601 330.7 82.6901C330.63 81.3901 330.31 79.5001 330.09 78.2201C329.95 77.3701 330.52 76.5701 331.36 76.4301C332.21 76.2901 333.01 76.8601 333.15 77.7001C333.39 79.1201 333.75 81.2601 333.81 82.7501L333.82 82.9501L333.77 83.1501C331.97 91.2001 325.86 130.64 325.8 131.04C325.69 131.81 325.03 132.36 324.28 132.36Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M335.99 129.36C335.96 129.36 335.92 129.36 335.89 129.36C335.04 129.31 334.39 128.57 334.44 127.71C334.46 127.37 336.66 93.1402 336.43 84.4802L336.42 84.2102L338.12 78.9702C338.38 78.1602 339.26 77.7102 340.07 77.9702C340.89 78.2302 341.33 79.1102 341.07 79.9202L339.53 84.6502C339.72 93.8402 337.62 126.5 337.53 127.89C337.49 128.73 336.8 129.36 335.99 129.36Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M370.19 184.08C369.38 184.08 368.7 183.45 368.64 182.63L366.65 150.72C366.6 149.87 367.25 149.13 368.1 149.07C368.96 149.03 369.69 149.67 369.74 150.52L371.74 182.43C371.79 183.28 371.14 184.02 370.29 184.07C370.25 184.08 370.22 184.08 370.19 184.08Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M300.9 159.76C296.45 159.76 295.33 157.53 294.53 154.85C294.34 154.23 294.17 153.64 293.91 153.14C293.51 152.39 293.79 151.44 294.55 151.04C295.31 150.63 296.25 150.92 296.65 151.68C297.06 152.45 297.3 153.25 297.51 153.96C298.17 156.17 298.6 157.62 305.56 156C316.79 153.38 336.61 149.13 351.09 146.02C355.22 145.13 358.82 144.36 361.5 143.78C363.1 138.06 365.38 130.97 367.77 123.5C370.89 113.75 374.12 103.68 375.84 96.64C377.3 82.8 367.62 78.46 358.26 74.27L357.8 74.06C357.02 73.71 356.67 72.79 357.02 72.01C357.37 71.23 358.29 70.88 359.07 71.23L359.53 71.44C368.95 75.66 380.67 80.91 378.92 97.08C378.91 97.15 378.9 97.21 378.88 97.28C377.15 104.43 373.88 114.61 370.73 124.45C368.21 132.3 365.84 139.71 364.24 145.52C364.09 146.08 363.64 146.5 363.07 146.63C360.32 147.23 356.36 148.08 351.73 149.07C338.08 152 317.46 156.42 306.25 159.04C304.08 159.53 302.32 159.75 300.9 159.76Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M304.58 87.15C304.25 87.15 303.92 87.05 303.64 86.83C302.96 86.31 302.83 85.34 303.35 84.66L311 74.69C311.19 74.45 311.44 74.27 311.72 74.17L329 68.19C329.81 67.91 330.69 68.34 330.97 69.15C331.25 69.96 330.82 70.84 330.01 71.12L313.17 76.95L305.81 86.55C305.51 86.95 305.05 87.15 304.58 87.15Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M318.01 341.3H292.45L292.17 341.19C290.88 340.67 289.94 339.32 289.67 337.59C289.37 335.71 289.86 333.03 292.11 331.16C293.54 329.97 293.98 329.67 296.37 328.44C300.16 290 307.74 172.74 307.82 171.55C307.87 170.7 308.61 170.05 309.47 170.1C310.32 170.15 310.97 170.89 310.92 171.75C310.84 172.95 303.14 292 299.38 329.58L299.3 330.42L298.55 330.81C295.54 332.35 295.4 332.46 294.11 333.54C292.85 334.59 292.58 336.07 292.74 337.11C292.82 337.65 293.02 338.02 293.19 338.2H315.35C317.17 326.3 330.73 237.04 334.5 195.32L334.65 193.67L336.28 193.92C336.51 193.96 337.11 194.02 337.79 194.09C338.71 194.19 339.74 194.3 340.26 194.38L341.41 194.56L341.56 195.72C345.89 228.94 352.54 297.48 355.46 329.08L355.55 330.04L354.73 330.54C353.79 331.12 353.01 331.55 352.32 331.93C351.56 332.35 350.9 332.71 350.25 333.15C348.9 334.07 347.88 336.36 347.91 337.2C350.79 337.57 364.42 337.28 371.14 337.1L366.64 191.56C366.61 190.7 367.29 189.99 368.14 189.96C368.97 189.93 369.71 190.61 369.74 191.46L374.33 340.11L372.78 340.16C371.9 340.19 351.09 340.81 347.36 340.26C346.17 340.14 345.23 339.34 344.93 338.14C344.32 335.73 346.38 332.04 348.5 330.59C349.28 330.05 350.04 329.64 350.84 329.2C351.3 328.95 351.77 328.69 352.29 328.39C349.37 296.78 342.93 230.56 338.65 197.31C338.26 197.27 337.84 197.22 337.47 197.18C337.46 197.18 337.46 197.18 337.45 197.18C333.2 242.51 318.36 339 318.21 339.98L318.01 341.3Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M340.8 76.2C335.52 76.2 330.78 72.39 330.53 72.18L329.92 71.68L329.96 70.89C329.96 70.85 330.18 66.81 329.99 62.23C326.01 58.58 323.77 53.29 323.32 46.48C322.23 30.16 324.25 25.82 324.48 25.38C324.88 24.62 325.82 24.33 326.58 24.73C327.34 25.13 327.62 26.07 327.22 26.83C327.22 26.83 325.39 30.94 326.41 46.27C326.83 52.5 328.88 57.22 332.51 60.31L333.02 60.74L333.05 61.41C333.24 65.2 333.15 68.66 333.09 70.2C334.82 71.41 339.95 74.53 344.04 72.26C344.79 71.84 345.73 72.11 346.15 72.86C346.57 73.61 346.3 74.55 345.55 74.97C343.99 75.86 342.37 76.2 340.8 76.2Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M356.44 37.6301C356.36 37.6301 356.28 37.6201 356.2 37.6101C355.35 37.4801 354.78 36.6801 354.91 35.8401C354.92 35.7801 355.77 29.9201 352.75 23.5201C350.55 19.9301 344.93 16.7801 335.68 18.6501C331.75 19.4401 328.24 23.0001 327.16 27.2001C328.92 30.7401 334.68 31.0301 341.98 31.0301C347.36 31.0301 348.93 34.2801 349.01 36.0001C349.05 36.8601 348.39 37.5801 347.53 37.6201C346.68 37.6701 345.95 37.0001 345.91 36.1401C345.89 35.9701 345.6 34.1301 341.97 34.1301C335.06 34.1301 326.46 34.1301 324.07 27.9001L323.91 27.4701L324.01 27.0201C325.2 21.3701 329.74 16.6701 335.06 15.6001C345.95 13.4001 352.73 17.4501 355.44 21.9701L355.51 22.1001C359 29.4301 358.01 36.0301 357.97 36.3001C357.84 37.0901 357.19 37.6301 356.44 37.6301Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M340.03 197.19C339.94 197.19 339.85 197.18 339.75 197.17L331.56 195.7C330.72 195.55 330.15 194.74 330.31 193.9C330.46 193.06 331.26 192.49 332.11 192.65L340.3 194.12C341.14 194.27 341.7 195.08 341.55 195.92C341.42 196.67 340.76 197.19 340.03 197.19Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M359.76 74.86C359.48 74.86 359.19 74.78 358.93 74.62L351.95 70.21L350.75 51.39C350.7 50.53 351.35 49.8 352.2 49.74C353.04 49.69 353.79 50.33 353.85 51.19L354.95 68.43L360.59 72C361.31 72.46 361.53 73.42 361.07 74.14C360.77 74.6 360.27 74.86 359.76 74.86Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M351.02 52.2602C350.25 52.2602 349.58 51.6902 349.48 50.9002C349.37 50.0502 349.97 49.2702 350.83 49.1702C354.02 48.7702 354.77 47.4002 355.06 46.4102C355.55 44.7302 354.54 42.8802 352.81 42.3002C351.83 41.9702 350.81 42.1002 350.01 42.6702C349.31 43.1702 348.34 43.0002 347.85 42.3002C347.35 41.6002 347.52 40.6302 348.22 40.1402C349.81 39.0102 351.9 38.7202 353.81 39.3602C357.1 40.4702 359 44.0302 358.04 47.2802C357.47 49.2202 355.83 51.6602 351.22 52.2402C351.15 52.2502 351.08 52.2602 351.02 52.2602Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M369.77 185.38H355.03C354.17 185.38 353.48 184.68 353.48 183.83C353.48 182.97 354.17 182.28 355.03 182.28H369.77C370.63 182.28 371.32 182.98 371.32 183.83C371.33 184.69 370.63 185.38 369.77 185.38Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M309.57 143.44C309.28 143.44 308.98 143.36 308.73 143.19L299.76 137.42C299.04 136.96 298.83 136 299.29 135.28C299.75 134.56 300.71 134.35 301.43 134.81L309.84 140.21L347.87 130.51L357.26 97.14C357.49 96.32 358.35 95.84 359.17 96.07C360 96.3 360.47 97.16 360.24 97.98L350.6 132.21C350.45 132.74 350.03 133.16 349.49 133.29L309.94 143.38C309.83 143.42 309.7 143.44 309.57 143.44Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M293.62 149.47C293.01 149.47 292.43 149.11 292.18 148.51C291.86 147.72 292.24 146.81 293.03 146.49L300.34 143.5C301.13 143.18 302.04 143.56 302.36 144.35C302.69 145.14 302.3 146.05 301.51 146.37L294.2 149.36C294.01 149.43 293.81 149.47 293.62 149.47Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M314.02 157.16C313.37 157.16 312.76 156.75 312.55 156.1L309.89 148.12C309.62 147.31 310.06 146.43 310.87 146.16C311.69 145.89 312.56 146.33 312.83 147.14L315.49 155.12C315.76 155.93 315.32 156.81 314.51 157.08C314.35 157.14 314.18 157.16 314.02 157.16Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M334.98 63.53C332.78 63.53 331.16 63.02 331.03 62.98C330.21 62.72 329.77 61.84 330.03 61.03C330.29 60.22 331.16 59.76 331.98 60.03C332.01 60.04 336.05 61.27 339.36 59.34C340.1 58.91 341.05 59.16 341.48 59.9C341.91 60.64 341.66 61.59 340.92 62.02C338.9 63.2 336.75 63.53 334.98 63.53Z" fill="black"/>
<path id="lamp2"d="M223.57 212.53C223.16 212.53 222.77 212.47 222.48 212.19C222.19 211.9 222.02 211.56 222.02 211.15L221.49 126.35C221.49 126.16 221.52 125.98 221.6 125.8C222.7 122.96 225.38 121.26 228.77 121.26C230.17 121.26 231.62 121.56 232.97 122.12C233.68 122.42 234.54 122.84 235.52 123.34C238.32 124.73 242.14 126.64 244.99 126.65C252.57 126.65 258.72 120.51 258.75 112.97C258.76 109.31 257.34 105.86 254.76 103.26C252.18 100.66 248.74 99.2301 245.08 99.2201C241.92 99.2201 237.74 101.42 234.7 103.03C233.69 103.56 232.82 104.02 232.1 104.34C230.97 104.85 229.78 105.1 228.55 105.1C225.46 105.1 222.75 103.48 221.48 100.88C221.38 100.67 221.33 100.44 221.32 100.21L221 46.8001C221 46.3801 221.16 45.9801 221.46 45.6801C221.76 45.3901 222.17 45.2201 222.58 45.2401C238.21 45.6001 256.2 47.4501 271.18 58.4501C287.27 70.2601 295.7 85.1501 296.94 103.97C297.83 117.42 293.58 138.48 268.28 162.41C267.74 162.92 267.27 163.37 267.13 163.53C252.19 180.36 251.3 210.76 251.29 211.06C251.27 211.9 250.59 212.46 249.75 212.47L223.57 212.53C223.58 212.53 223.57 212.53 223.57 212.53ZM224.6 126.67L225.11 209.63L248.26 209.49C248.62 202.94 250.9 177.15 264.82 161.48C265.05 161.22 265.47 160.82 266.16 160.17C290.58 137.07 294.7 116.98 293.86 104.19C293.11 92.8001 289.75 75.9301 269.36 60.9601C255.58 50.8401 239.54 48.8401 224.11 48.3901L224.43 99.8201C225.23 101.15 226.81 102 228.56 102C229.34 102 230.11 101.83 230.84 101.51C231.47 101.23 232.3 100.79 233.26 100.28C236.6 98.5201 241.16 96.1101 245.07 96.1101C249.59 96.1201 253.81 97.8801 256.97 101.07C260.14 104.26 261.87 108.48 261.86 112.97C261.83 122.22 254.29 129.74 245.04 129.74C241.42 129.73 237.22 127.64 234.15 126.11C233.21 125.64 232.4 125.24 231.79 124.98C230.82 124.57 229.78 124.36 228.78 124.36C227.82 124.36 225.56 124.6 224.6 126.67Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M226.57 225.72C225.72 225.72 225.02 224.88 225.02 224.02C225.01 223.16 225.7 222.22 226.56 222.21L247.47 221.83H247.48C248.33 221.83 249.03 222.69 249.03 223.54C249.04 224.4 248.35 225.33 247.49 225.34L226.57 225.72C226.58 225.72 226.57 225.72 226.57 225.72Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M227.13 239.68C226.28 239.68 225.58 238.97 225.58 238.12C225.57 237.26 226.27 236.62 227.12 236.62L242.9 236.58H242.91C243.76 236.58 244.46 237.2 244.46 238.06C244.47 238.92 243.77 239.6 242.92 239.6L227.13 239.68Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M312.36 130.31C311.51 130.31 310.82 129.59 310.81 128.74L310.48 98.6802C310.47 97.8202 311.16 96.9602 312.02 96.9602C312.02 96.9602 312.03 96.9602 312.04 96.9602C312.89 96.9602 313.58 97.7802 313.59 98.6302L313.92 128.65C313.93 129.51 313.24 130.32 312.39 130.32C312.37 130.31 312.36 130.31 312.36 130.31Z" fill="black"/>
</g>
<defs>
<clipPath id="clip0">
<rect y="75" width="460.76" height="266.82" fill="white"/>
</clipPath>
<clipPath id="clip1">
<rect x="70" width="207.82" height="341.13" fill="white"/>
</clipPath>
<clipPath id="clip2">
<rect x="221" y="15" width="225.57" height="326.3" fill="white"/>
</clipPath>
</defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: чем этот ответ отличался от того что я делал до этого ?

Comment: Немного не так как надо прорисовать сплошной линией без пустоты

Comment: какой сплошной линией ?

Answer (score 1):

Элементы SVG нарисованы изначально двойными контурами, поэтому применены для  рисования линий две анимации:

1. Анимация stroke-dasharray
2. Анимация заполнением цветом внутреннего контура

```
.lamp1 {
fill:none;
stroke:#111111;
stroke-dasharray:0,966;
animation:draw 10s linear forwards,lamp_fill 2s forwards 5s; 
}
@keyframes draw{
100% {stroke-dasharray:966,0;}
} 

@keyframes lamp_fill{
0% {fill:none;}
100% {fill:#111111;}
}
```

После анимации линии будут выглядеть несколько более толстыми, чем на исходном примере. 
Это происходит из-за двойного контура обводки (так нарисован пример в векторном редакторе)
Решение этой проблемы одно, - перерисовать svg изображение одиночными контурами.
Как например сделано в ответе @MaximLensky

```css
.lamp1 {
fill:none;
stroke:#111111;
stroke-dasharray:0,966;
animation:draw 10s linear forwards,lamp_fill 2s forwards 5s; 
}
@keyframes draw{
100% {stroke-dasharray:966,0;}
} 

@keyframes lamp_fill{
0% {fill:none;}
100% {fill:#111111;}
}  

.lamp2 {
fill:none;
stroke:#111111;
stroke-dasharray:0,966;
animation:draw2 5s linear forwards,lamp_fill 2s forwards 5s,lamp_tr 2s linear forwards 7s; 
}
@keyframes draw2{
100% {stroke-dasharray:966,0;}
} 

@keyframes lamp_fill{
0% {fill:none;}
100% {fill:#111111;}
}
```

```html
<svg width="461" height="342" viewBox="0 0 461 342" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<g> 
<path class="yell"    d="M261.34 150.95C261.34 192.89 227.34 226.9 185.39 226.9C143.44 226.9 109.44 192.9 109.44 150.95C109.45 109 143.45 75 185.4 75C227.34 75 261.34 109 261.34 150.95Z" fill="#F3EC18"/> 

<path d="M459.2 341.82H1.55C0.69 341.82 0 341.12 0 340.27C0 339.41 0.7 338.72 1.55 338.72H459.2C460.06 338.72 460.75 339.42 460.75 340.27C460.76 341.12 460.06 341.82 459.2 341.82Z" fill="black"/>
</g>
<g clip-path="url(#clip1)">
<path d="M123.85 153.28C123.78 153.28 123.71 153.28 123.64 153.27C122.79 153.15 122.2 152.37 122.32 151.52L122.82 147.91C122.94 147.06 123.72 146.47 124.57 146.58C125.42 146.7 126.01 147.48 125.9 148.33L125.4 151.94C125.28 152.72 124.61 153.28 123.85 153.28Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M123.75 143.44C123.62 143.44 123.48 143.42 123.36 143.39L93.0396 135.41C92.4596 135.26 92.0196 134.78 91.9096 134.19L85.9296 101.62C85.7696 100.78 86.3296 99.97 87.1796 99.81C88.0296 99.66 88.8296 100.21 88.9896 101.06L94.7896 132.66L123.57 140.23L127.66 138.09C128.42 137.69 129.36 137.99 129.76 138.75C130.16 139.51 129.86 140.45 129.1 140.84L124.48 143.26C124.25 143.38 124 143.44 123.75 143.44Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M215.62 17.01C214.76 17.01 214.07 16.32 214.07 15.46V1.55C214.07 0.69 214.77 0 215.62 0C216.48 0 217.17 0.69 217.17 1.55V15.46C217.18 16.32 216.48 17.01 215.62 17.01Z" fill="#1A1A1A"/>
<path d="M164.41 38.6901C164.01 38.6901 163.62 38.5401 163.31 38.2401L154.88 29.8101C154.27 29.2001 154.27 28.2201 154.88 27.6201C155.49 27.0101 156.47 27.0101 157.07 27.6201L165.5 36.0501C166.11 36.6601 166.11 37.6401 165.5 38.2401C165.2 38.5401 164.81 38.6901 164.41 38.6901Z" fill="#1A1A1A"/>
<path d="M268.141 36.6901C267.741 36.6901 267.351 36.5401 267.041 36.2401C266.431 35.6301 266.431 34.6501 267.041 34.0501L275.171 25.9201C275.781 25.3201 276.761 25.3101 277.361 25.9201C277.971 26.5301 277.971 27.5101 277.361 28.1101L269.231 36.2401C268.931 36.5401 268.531 36.6901 268.141 36.6901Z" fill="#1A1A1A"/>

<path  class="lamp2" d="M223.57 212.53C223.16 212.53 222.77 212.47 222.48 212.19C222.19 211.9 222.02 211.56 222.02 211.15L221.49 126.35C221.49 126.16 221.52 125.98 221.6 125.8C222.7 122.96 225.38 121.26 228.77 121.26C230.17 121.26 231.62 121.56 232.97 122.12C233.68 122.42 234.54 122.84 235.52 123.34C238.32 124.73 242.14 126.64 244.99 126.65C252.57 126.65 258.72 120.51 258.75 112.97C258.76 109.31 257.34 105.86 254.76 103.26C252.18 100.66 248.74 99.2301 245.08 99.2201C241.92 99.2201 237.74 101.42 234.7 103.03C233.69 103.56 232.82 104.02 232.1 104.34C230.97 104.85 229.78 105.1 228.55 105.1C225.46 105.1 222.75 103.48 221.48 100.88C221.38 100.67 221.33 100.44 221.32 100.21L221 46.8001C221 46.3801 221.16 45.9801 221.46 45.6801C221.76 45.3901 222.17 45.2201 222.58 45.2401C238.21 45.6001 256.2 47.4501 271.18 58.4501C287.27 70.2601 295.7 85.1501 296.94 103.97C297.83 117.42 293.58 138.48 268.28 162.41C267.74 162.92 267.27 163.37 267.13 163.53C252.19 180.36 251.3 210.76 251.29 211.06C251.27 211.9 250.59 212.46 249.75 212.47L223.57 212.53C223.58 212.53 223.57 212.53 223.57 212.53ZM224.6 126.67L225.11 209.63L248.26 209.49C248.62 202.94 250.9 177.15 264.82 161.48C265.05 161.22 265.47 160.82 266.16 160.17C290.58 137.07 294.7 116.98 293.86 104.19C293.11 92.8001 289.75 75.9301 269.36 60.9601C255.58 50.8401 239.54 48.8401 224.11 48.3901L224.43 99.8201C225.23 101.15 226.81 102 228.56 102C229.34 102 230.11 101.83 230.84 101.51C231.47 101.23 232.3 100.79 233.26 100.28C236.6 98.5201 241.16 96.1101 245.07 96.1101C249.59 96.1201 253.81 97.8801 256.97 101.07C260.14 104.26 261.87 108.48 261.86 112.97C261.83 122.22 254.29 129.74 245.04 129.74C241.42 129.73 237.22 127.64 234.15 126.11C233.21 125.64 232.4 125.24 231.79 124.98C230.82 124.57 229.78 124.36 228.78 124.36C227.82 124.36 225.56 124.6 224.6 126.67Z" fill="none" stroke="black"/> 

<path class="lamp2" d="M226.57 225.72C225.72 225.72 225.02 224.88 225.02 224.02C225.01 223.16 225.7 222.22 226.56 222.21L247.47 221.83H247.48C248.33 221.83 249.03 222.69 249.03 223.54C249.04 224.4 248.35 225.33 247.49 225.34L226.57 225.72C226.58 225.72 226.57 225.72 226.57 225.72Z" stroke="black" fill="none"/> 

<path class="lamp2" d="M227.13 239.68C226.28 239.68 225.58 238.97 225.58 238.12C225.57 237.26 226.27 236.62 227.12 236.62L242.9 236.58H242.91C243.76 236.58 244.46 237.2 244.46 238.06C244.47 238.92 243.77 239.6 242.92 239.6L227.13 239.68Z" stroke="black" fill="none"/>   

<path class="lamp1"  d="M189.89 234.13C189.08 234.13 188.4 233.5 188.35 232.68C188.33 232.34 185.81 198.72 166 182.55C152.11 171.2 142.91 152.89 142 134.76C141.11 116.97 146.48 100.14 157.13 87.39C168.01 74.36 183.58 66.7 200.97 65.83C201.27 65.81 201.57 65.8 201.92 65.79L202.3 65.78C203.16 65.74 203.87 66.4 203.91 67.25L206.19 112.79C206.19 112.84 206.19 112.89 206.19 112.93C206.12 114.64 206.66 116.19 207.73 117.3C209.15 118.78 211.34 119.23 213.11 118.35C214.1 117.86 215.16 117.01 216.38 116.02C219.46 113.54 223.29 110.45 229.55 110.14C229.85 110.12 230.15 110.12 230.45 110.12C239.85 110.12 247.01 117.05 247.85 126.97C248.41 133.6 245.83 137.91 243.57 140.37C240.44 143.77 235.97 145.72 231.31 145.72C230.91 145.72 230.5 145.72 230.1 145.68C225.49 145.34 220.93 143.44 217.27 141.91C216.29 141.5 215.37 141.12 214.58 140.82C212.82 140.16 210.95 140.61 209.6 141.98C208.48 143.12 207.84 144.75 207.87 146.45L212.13 231.46C212.15 231.87 212.01 232.27 211.73 232.58C211.45 232.88 211.07 233.07 210.66 233.09L189.98 234.13C189.95 234.13 189.92 234.13 189.89 234.13ZM200.89 68.9401C167.29 70.7501 143.32 98.94 145.1 134.61C145.97 151.89 154.72 169.34 167.96 180.15C186.58 195.36 190.59 223.97 191.31 230.95L208.96 230.07L204.78 146.56C204.74 143.98 205.69 141.54 207.4 139.81C209.6 137.58 212.78 136.84 215.68 137.93C216.52 138.25 217.48 138.64 218.48 139.06C221.94 140.5 226.24 142.3 230.35 142.61C230.68 142.63 231 142.65 231.33 142.65C235.12 142.65 238.76 141.06 241.3 138.3C243.14 136.3 245.24 132.75 244.77 127.25C244.07 119 238.19 113.24 230.47 113.24C230.22 113.24 229.97 113.25 229.72 113.26C224.46 113.52 221.21 116.15 218.34 118.46C217.03 119.52 215.79 120.52 214.49 121.16C213.44 121.68 212.32 121.94 211.16 121.94C209.06 121.94 206.99 121.04 205.49 119.47C203.85 117.76 203 115.43 203.09 112.9L200.89 68.9401Z" fill="none" stroke="black"/>  

<path class="lamp1" d="M193.64 247.17C192.82 247.17 192.13 246.53 192.09 245.7C192.05 244.84 192.71 244.12 193.56 244.07L212 243.15C212.84 243.12 213.59 243.77 213.63 244.62C213.67 245.48 213.01 246.2 212.16 246.25L193.71 247.17C193.7 247.16 193.67 247.17 193.64 247.17Z" stroke="black" fill="none"/>
<path class="lamp1" d="M201.06 260.79C200.24 260.79 199.55 260.15 199.51 259.32C199.47 258.46 200.13 257.73 200.98 257.69L212.19 257.13C213.04 257.09 213.77 257.75 213.81 258.6C213.85 259.46 213.19 260.18 212.34 260.23L201.13 260.79C201.11 260.79 201.09 260.79 201.06 260.79Z" stroke="black" fill="none"/>
<path d="M106.82 186.06C106.02 186.06 105.34 185.29 105.28 184.49L104.54 175.32C104.47 174.46 105.11 173.68 105.96 173.61C106.83 173.54 107.56 174.16 107.63 175.01L108.25 182.6C112.62 182.35 125.63 181.31 132.81 177.47C131.19 173.09 129.87 166.75 129.81 166.46C129.64 165.62 130.17 164.8 131.01 164.63C131.84 164.45 132.67 164.99 132.84 165.83C132.86 165.91 134.45 173.53 136.17 177.53C136.47 178.23 136.22 179.19 135.58 179.6C126.64 185.28 107.68 186.06 106.87 186.06C106.85 186.06 106.84 186.06 106.82 186.06Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M101.35 185.96C90.2696 185.96 75.4196 182.43 74.7996 182.28C74.0496 182.1 73.5396 181.39 73.6196 180.62C73.6996 179.86 75.4596 161.89 76.4596 155.6C76.5896 154.75 77.3996 154.18 78.2296 154.31C79.0796 154.44 79.6496 155.24 79.5196 156.08C78.6996 161.29 77.2796 175.15 76.8396 179.56C80.7396 180.42 92.4996 182.85 101.35 182.85C102.21 182.85 102.9 183.55 102.9 184.4C102.9 185.26 102.2 185.96 101.35 185.96Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M120.93 328.14C120.16 328.14 119.49 327.56 119.39 326.77C118.54 319.71 117.56 313.73 116.43 306.81C113.65 289.8 109.85 266.5 104.53 206.05C104.45 205.2 105.09 204.44 105.94 204.37C106.8 204.29 107.55 204.93 107.62 205.78C112.92 266.12 116.72 289.35 119.49 306.32C120.62 313.28 121.61 319.28 122.47 326.41C122.57 327.26 121.97 328.03 121.12 328.14C121.05 328.14 120.99 328.14 120.93 328.14Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M73.83 327.86C73.01 327.86 72.32 327.21 72.28 326.38C71.89 318.52 71.73 309.06 71.53 297.08C71.39 288.56 71.23 278.91 70.95 268.01C70.83 263.39 70.67 259.01 70.51 254.77C69.74 233.88 69.07 215.83 74.65 188.98C74.82 188.14 75.65 187.6 76.48 187.78C77.32 187.95 77.86 188.78 77.68 189.61C72.18 216.09 72.84 233.96 73.61 254.66C73.77 258.9 73.93 263.29 74.05 267.93C74.33 278.84 74.49 288.51 74.64 297.03C74.84 308.98 75 318.41 75.38 326.23C75.42 327.09 74.76 327.81 73.91 327.86C73.88 327.85 73.85 327.86 73.83 327.86Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M139.26 341.13C137.61 341.13 135.42 339.94 131.39 337.74C130.78 337.41 130.14 337.06 129.46 336.69C129.22 338.02 129.13 338.78 129.13 339.56C129.13 340.39 128.47 341.08 127.64 341.11C127.36 341.12 123.9 341.11 122.84 341.11C122.01 341.11 121.33 340.45 121.29 339.62L120.79 327.16C120.76 326.3 121.42 325.58 122.28 325.55C123.17 325.52 123.86 326.18 123.89 327.04L124.33 338.02C124.95 338.02 125.58 338.02 126.12 338.02C126.23 337.06 126.45 335.89 126.8 334.04C126.89 333.56 127.21 333.15 127.65 332.93C128.09 332.72 128.61 332.73 129.04 332.96C130.45 333.71 131.72 334.4 132.86 335.02C135.66 336.55 138.57 338.14 139.32 338.03C140.26 337.94 140.86 337.83 141.24 337.73C141.23 337.72 141.23 337.72 141.22 337.71C138.48 335.16 137.45 333.32 135.9 330.53C135.36 329.56 134.75 328.46 133.97 327.16C133.53 326.42 133.77 325.47 134.5 325.03C135.23 324.59 136.19 324.83 136.63 325.56C137.44 326.91 138.06 328.03 138.61 329.02C140.12 331.73 140.95 333.23 143.33 335.44C144.55 336.57 144.98 337.69 144.61 338.77C144.04 340.46 141.9 340.89 139.68 341.11C139.56 341.12 139.41 341.13 139.26 341.13Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M90.4102 341.13C88.7602 341.13 86.5702 339.93 82.5402 337.74C81.9402 337.41 81.4802 337.06 80.8002 336.69C80.5502 338.08 80.6602 338.8 80.6602 339.56V341.05L78.9802 341.11C78.7002 341.12 75.1402 341.11 74.0902 341.11H72.5602L71.9802 327.16C71.9402 326.3 72.6002 325.58 73.4602 325.55C74.3502 325.52 75.0302 326.18 75.0702 327.04L75.5102 338.02C76.1302 338.02 76.7602 338.02 77.3002 338.02C77.4102 337.06 77.6302 335.89 77.9802 334.04L78.3802 331.98L80.2302 332.96C81.6402 333.71 82.9102 334.4 84.0502 335.02C86.8502 336.55 89.7402 338.13 90.5102 338.03C91.4502 337.94 92.0502 337.83 92.4302 337.73C92.4202 337.72 92.4202 337.72 92.4102 337.71C89.6702 335.16 88.6402 333.32 87.0902 330.52C86.5502 329.55 85.9402 328.45 85.1602 327.15C84.7202 326.41 84.9602 325.46 85.6902 325.02C86.4202 324.58 87.3802 324.82 87.8202 325.55C88.6302 326.9 89.2502 328.02 89.8002 329.01C91.3102 331.72 92.1402 333.22 94.5202 335.43C95.7402 336.56 96.1702 337.68 95.8002 338.76C95.2302 340.45 93.0902 340.88 90.8702 341.1C90.7002 341.12 90.5602 341.13 90.4102 341.13Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M103.08 77.3C102.55 77.3 102.03 77.02 101.74 76.53C101.31 75.79 101.56 74.84 102.3 74.41L104.57 73.09L104.2 62.6L105.24 62.21C105.4 62.15 109.29 60.6 109.79 56.68C110.69 49.65 107.03 39.21 106.99 39.11C106.7 38.3 107.13 37.42 107.93 37.13C108.74 36.84 109.62 37.27 109.91 38.07C110.07 38.53 113.85 49.31 112.86 57.07C112.31 61.4 109.07 63.7 107.37 64.62L107.72 74.84L103.85 77.09C103.61 77.23 103.34 77.3 103.08 77.3Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M76.1496 77.6299C75.6896 77.6299 75.2296 77.4199 74.9196 77.0299C69.6496 70.1899 71.0696 57.3899 79.2696 37.8999C83.2196 26.0899 90.4696 20.9599 100.82 22.6399C107.41 23.7099 111.65 26.4999 113.77 31.1699L114.01 31.6999L113.85 32.2499C112.2 37.8599 106.9 41.9699 100.34 42.7299C96.9396 43.1199 92.4096 42.4999 92.2196 42.4799C91.3696 42.3599 90.7796 41.5799 90.8996 40.7299C91.0196 39.8799 91.7996 39.2899 92.6496 39.4099C92.6896 39.4199 96.9796 39.9999 99.9896 39.6499C105.08 39.0599 109.22 36.0599 110.7 31.9299C108.95 28.5899 105.55 26.5499 100.33 25.6999C91.5696 24.2799 85.6396 28.5999 82.1996 38.9299L82.1596 39.0399C74.6296 56.9299 72.9796 69.4099 77.3796 75.1299C77.8996 75.8099 77.7796 76.7799 77.0996 77.3099C76.8196 77.5299 76.4896 77.6299 76.1496 77.6299Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M120.69 71.9799C120.41 71.9799 120.13 71.8999 119.88 71.7499C119.15 71.2999 118.93 70.3399 119.38 69.6099C120.75 67.3899 124.2 58.1699 110.99 32.5099C110.6 31.7499 110.9 30.8099 111.66 30.4199C112.42 30.0299 113.36 30.3299 113.75 31.0899C126.83 56.5099 124.54 67.1599 122.01 71.2399C121.71 71.7199 121.21 71.9799 120.69 71.9799Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M133.13 155.62L126.55 154.38L85.8502 147.89C83.6002 147.54 79.2602 145.62 79.0302 140.84C78.9602 139.26 77.8002 133.56 76.4602 126.96C74.0602 115.14 71.0702 100.44 70.9402 93.66C70.7402 83.46 75.8702 81.1399 79.6102 79.4499C80.1702 79.1999 80.7002 78.9599 81.1902 78.6999L90.8202 74.1999L90.6802 55.8699C90.6702 55.0099 91.3602 54.2 92.2202 54.2H92.2302C93.0802 54.2 93.7702 54.9899 93.7802 55.8499L93.9302 76.12L82.5502 81.4599C82.0502 81.7199 81.4502 81.9999 80.8802 82.2699C77.2802 83.8999 73.8802 85.4399 74.0302 93.5999C74.1502 100.1 77.2402 115.27 79.4802 126.35C80.9602 133.63 82.0302 138.89 82.1102 140.71C82.2702 144.14 86.1502 144.82 86.3202 144.84L127.06 151.34L132.95 152.45C133.48 152.26 134.64 151.8 136 150.91C136.72 150.44 137.68 150.64 138.15 151.36C138.62 152.08 138.42 153.04 137.7 153.51C135.4 155.02 133.52 155.53 133.45 155.56L133.13 155.62Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M90.8205 58.55C90.7805 58.55 90.7305 58.55 90.6805 58.54C87.2605 58.24 85.0305 56.79 84.0405 54.23C83.4805 52.77 83.5205 51.18 84.1505 49.75C84.7805 48.32 85.9405 47.23 87.4005 46.66C89.1205 46 91.0805 46.19 92.6405 47.18C93.3605 47.64 93.5805 48.6 93.1205 49.32C92.6605 50.04 91.7005 50.26 90.9805 49.8C90.2505 49.34 89.3305 49.24 88.5205 49.56C87.8305 49.82 87.2905 50.34 86.9905 51.01C86.6905 51.68 86.6705 52.43 86.9405 53.11C87.2805 53.99 88.0605 55.18 90.9605 55.44C91.8105 55.52 92.4405 56.27 92.3705 57.12C92.2905 57.95 91.6205 58.55 90.8205 58.55Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M103.41 206.39C102.77 206.39 102.17 205.99 101.95 205.36C101.66 204.55 102.08 203.67 102.89 203.38L111.86 200.18C112.66 199.89 113.55 200.31 113.84 201.12C114.13 201.93 113.71 202.82 112.9 203.1L103.93 206.3C103.76 206.36 103.58 206.39 103.41 206.39Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M88.26 328.01H82.8C81.94 328.01 81.25 327.31 81.25 326.46C81.25 325.6 81.94 324.91 82.8 324.91H85.55C88.06 307.07 103.38 206.47 103.54 205.43C103.67 204.58 104.46 204.04 105.31 204.16C106.16 204.29 106.74 205.1 106.61 205.94C106.45 207.01 90.25 313.12 88.45 326.71L88.26 328.01Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M129.64 328.46C128.82 328.46 128.14 327.82 128.09 327C128.04 326.14 128.69 325.41 129.55 325.36L133.38 325.14C131.57 301.94 132.68 280.39 133.75 259.54C135.07 233.91 136.32 209.71 131.79 186.06C131.63 185.22 132.18 184.41 133.02 184.25C133.87 184.09 134.67 184.64 134.83 185.48C139.43 209.49 138.17 233.88 136.84 259.7C135.75 280.92 134.62 302.87 136.59 326.47L136.72 328.06L129.72 328.47C129.7 328.46 129.67 328.46 129.64 328.46Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M107.39 106.94C106.55 106.94 105.86 106.24 105.84 105.39L105.6 95.08L90.5897 77.08C90.0397 76.42 90.1297 75.44 90.7897 74.89C91.4497 74.34 92.4197 74.43 92.9697 75.09L108.33 93.5C108.55 93.77 108.68 94.11 108.69 94.46L108.95 105.33C108.97 106.19 108.29 106.95 107.44 106.95C107.42 106.94 107.41 106.94 107.39 106.94Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M140.8 104.05C140.61 104.05 140.42 104.01 140.23 103.94C139.49 103.65 139.19 103.33 132.74 93.82C129.4 88.9 124.44 81.57 123.09 80.21C118.66 79.49 114.57 78.53 112.52 78.02L108.65 94.83C108.46 95.67 107.62 96.19 106.79 95.99C105.96 95.8 105.43 94.97 105.63 94.13L109.9 75.6C110.04 75 110.51 74.54 111.12 74.43C111.61 74.33 112.11 74.48 112.46 74.81C113.98 75.2 118.82 76.4 123.94 77.21C125.09 77.39 125.78 78.02 135.32 92.09C137.99 96.03 141.02 100.49 141.72 101.25C142.28 101.66 142.52 102.4 142.26 103.08C142 103.68 141.41 104.05 140.8 104.05Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M129.33 124.16C129.31 124.16 129.29 124.16 129.27 124.16C128.41 124.13 127.74 123.41 127.78 122.55L128.44 103.94C128.47 103.08 129.18 102.41 130.05 102.44C130.91 102.47 131.58 103.19 131.54 104.05L130.88 122.66C130.85 123.5 130.16 124.16 129.33 124.16Z" fill="black"/>
</g>
<g clip-path="url(#clip2)">
<path d="M417.05 136.93L406.78 126.66L417.05 116.39L427.33 126.66L417.05 136.93ZM410.06 126.65L417.04 133.63L424.02 126.65L417.04 119.67L410.06 126.65Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M427.16 254.91C427.16 256.55 425.83 257.88 424.19 257.88C422.55 257.88 421.21 256.55 421.21 254.91C421.21 253.27 422.54 251.93 424.19 251.93C425.83 251.93 427.16 253.27 427.16 254.91Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M397.14 163.18C397.14 164.76 395.85 166.05 394.27 166.05C392.68 166.05 391.4 164.77 391.4 163.18C391.4 161.59 392.69 160.31 394.27 160.31C395.86 160.31 397.14 161.59 397.14 163.18Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M445.01 223.39H412.43C411.57 223.39 410.88 222.69 410.88 221.84C410.88 220.98 411.57 220.29 412.43 220.29H445.01C445.87 220.29 446.56 220.99 446.56 221.84C446.57 222.7 445.87 223.39 445.01 223.39Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M414.76 202.45H398.47C397.61 202.45 396.92 201.75 396.92 200.9C396.92 200.04 397.62 199.35 398.47 199.35H414.76C415.62 199.35 416.31 200.05 416.31 200.9C416.32 201.75 415.62 202.45 414.76 202.45Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M324.28 132.36C324.2 132.36 324.12 132.35 324.04 132.34C323.19 132.21 322.61 131.42 322.74 130.57C322.99 128.96 328.82 91.2601 330.7 82.6901C330.63 81.3901 330.31 79.5001 330.09 78.2201C329.95 77.3701 330.52 76.5701 331.36 76.4301C332.21 76.2901 333.01 76.8601 333.15 77.7001C333.39 79.1201 333.75 81.2601 333.81 82.7501L333.82 82.9501L333.77 83.1501C331.97 91.2001 325.86 130.64 325.8 131.04C325.69 131.81 325.03 132.36 324.28 132.36Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M335.99 129.36C335.96 129.36 335.92 129.36 335.89 129.36C335.04 129.31 334.39 128.57 334.44 127.71C334.46 127.37 336.66 93.1402 336.43 84.4802L336.42 84.2102L338.12 78.9702C338.38 78.1602 339.26 77.7102 340.07 77.9702C340.89 78.2302 341.33 79.1102 341.07 79.9202L339.53 84.6502C339.72 93.8402 337.62 126.5 337.53 127.89C337.49 128.73 336.8 129.36 335.99 129.36Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M370.19 184.08C369.38 184.08 368.7 183.45 368.64 182.63L366.65 150.72C366.6 149.87 367.25 149.13 368.1 149.07C368.96 149.03 369.69 149.67 369.74 150.52L371.74 182.43C371.79 183.28 371.14 184.02 370.29 184.07C370.25 184.08 370.22 184.08 370.19 184.08Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M300.9 159.76C296.45 159.76 295.33 157.53 294.53 154.85C294.34 154.23 294.17 153.64 293.91 153.14C293.51 152.39 293.79 151.44 294.55 151.04C295.31 150.63 296.25 150.92 296.65 151.68C297.06 152.45 297.3 153.25 297.51 153.96C298.17 156.17 298.6 157.62 305.56 156C316.79 153.38 336.61 149.13 351.09 146.02C355.22 145.13 358.82 144.36 361.5 143.78C363.1 138.06 365.38 130.97 367.77 123.5C370.89 113.75 374.12 103.68 375.84 96.64C377.3 82.8 367.62 78.46 358.26 74.27L357.8 74.06C357.02 73.71 356.67 72.79 357.02 72.01C357.37 71.23 358.29 70.88 359.07 71.23L359.53 71.44C368.95 75.66 380.67 80.91 378.92 97.08C378.91 97.15 378.9 97.21 378.88 97.28C377.15 104.43 373.88 114.61 370.73 124.45C368.21 132.3 365.84 139.71 364.24 145.52C364.09 146.08 363.64 146.5 363.07 146.63C360.32 147.23 356.36 148.08 351.73 149.07C338.08 152 317.46 156.42 306.25 159.04C304.08 159.53 302.32 159.75 300.9 159.76Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M304.58 87.15C304.25 87.15 303.92 87.05 303.64 86.83C302.96 86.31 302.83 85.34 303.35 84.66L311 74.69C311.19 74.45 311.44 74.27 311.72 74.17L329 68.19C329.81 67.91 330.69 68.34 330.97 69.15C331.25 69.96 330.82 70.84 330.01 71.12L313.17 76.95L305.81 86.55C305.51 86.95 305.05 87.15 304.58 87.15Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M318.01 341.3H292.45L292.17 341.19C290.88 340.67 289.94 339.32 289.67 337.59C289.37 335.71 289.86 333.03 292.11 331.16C293.54 329.97 293.98 329.67 296.37 328.44C300.16 290 307.74 172.74 307.82 171.55C307.87 170.7 308.61 170.05 309.47 170.1C310.32 170.15 310.97 170.89 310.92 171.75C310.84 172.95 303.14 292 299.38 329.58L299.3 330.42L298.55 330.81C295.54 332.35 295.4 332.46 294.11 333.54C292.85 334.59 292.58 336.07 292.74 337.11C292.82 337.65 293.02 338.02 293.19 338.2H315.35C317.17 326.3 330.73 237.04 334.5 195.32L334.65 193.67L336.28 193.92C336.51 193.96 337.11 194.02 337.79 194.09C338.71 194.19 339.74 194.3 340.26 194.38L341.41 194.56L341.56 195.72C345.89 228.94 352.54 297.48 355.46 329.08L355.55 330.04L354.73 330.54C353.79 331.12 353.01 331.55 352.32 331.93C351.56 332.35 350.9 332.71 350.25 333.15C348.9 334.07 347.88 336.36 347.91 337.2C350.79 337.57 364.42 337.28 371.14 337.1L366.64 191.56C366.61 190.7 367.29 189.99 368.14 189.96C368.97 189.93 369.71 190.61 369.74 191.46L374.33 340.11L372.78 340.16C371.9 340.19 351.09 340.81 347.36 340.26C346.17 340.14 345.23 339.34 344.93 338.14C344.32 335.73 346.38 332.04 348.5 330.59C349.28 330.05 350.04 329.64 350.84 329.2C351.3 328.95 351.77 328.69 352.29 328.39C349.37 296.78 342.93 230.56 338.65 197.31C338.26 197.27 337.84 197.22 337.47 197.18C337.46 197.18 337.46 197.18 337.45 197.18C333.2 242.51 318.36 339 318.21 339.98L318.01 341.3Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M340.8 76.2C335.52 76.2 330.78 72.39 330.53 72.18L329.92 71.68L329.96 70.89C329.96 70.85 330.18 66.81 329.99 62.23C326.01 58.58 323.77 53.29 323.32 46.48C322.23 30.16 324.25 25.82 324.48 25.38C324.88 24.62 325.82 24.33 326.58 24.73C327.34 25.13 327.62 26.07 327.22 26.83C327.22 26.83 325.39 30.94 326.41 46.27C326.83 52.5 328.88 57.22 332.51 60.31L333.02 60.74L333.05 61.41C333.24 65.2 333.15 68.66 333.09 70.2C334.82 71.41 339.95 74.53 344.04 72.26C344.79 71.84 345.73 72.11 346.15 72.86C346.57 73.61 346.3 74.55 345.55 74.97C343.99 75.86 342.37 76.2 340.8 76.2Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M356.44 37.6301C356.36 37.6301 356.28 37.6201 356.2 37.6101C355.35 37.4801 354.78 36.6801 354.91 35.8401C354.92 35.7801 355.77 29.9201 352.75 23.5201C350.55 19.9301 344.93 16.7801 335.68 18.6501C331.75 19.4401 328.24 23.0001 327.16 27.2001C328.92 30.7401 334.68 31.0301 341.98 31.0301C347.36 31.0301 348.93 34.2801 349.01 36.0001C349.05 36.8601 348.39 37.5801 347.53 37.6201C346.68 37.6701 345.95 37.0001 345.91 36.1401C345.89 35.9701 345.6 34.1301 341.97 34.1301C335.06 34.1301 326.46 34.1301 324.07 27.9001L323.91 27.4701L324.01 27.0201C325.2 21.3701 329.74 16.6701 335.06 15.6001C345.95 13.4001 352.73 17.4501 355.44 21.9701L355.51 22.1001C359 29.4301 358.01 36.0301 357.97 36.3001C357.84 37.0901 357.19 37.6301 356.44 37.6301Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M340.03 197.19C339.94 197.19 339.85 197.18 339.75 197.17L331.56 195.7C330.72 195.55 330.15 194.74 330.31 193.9C330.46 193.06 331.26 192.49 332.11 192.65L340.3 194.12C341.14 194.27 341.7 195.08 341.55 195.92C341.42 196.67 340.76 197.19 340.03 197.19Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M359.76 74.86C359.48 74.86 359.19 74.78 358.93 74.62L351.95 70.21L350.75 51.39C350.7 50.53 351.35 49.8 352.2 49.74C353.04 49.69 353.79 50.33 353.85 51.19L354.95 68.43L360.59 72C361.31 72.46 361.53 73.42 361.07 74.14C360.77 74.6 360.27 74.86 359.76 74.86Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M351.02 52.2602C350.25 52.2602 349.58 51.6902 349.48 50.9002C349.37 50.0502 349.97 49.2702 350.83 49.1702C354.02 48.7702 354.77 47.4002 355.06 46.4102C355.55 44.7302 354.54 42.8802 352.81 42.3002C351.83 41.9702 350.81 42.1002 350.01 42.6702C349.31 43.1702 348.34 43.0002 347.85 42.3002C347.35 41.6002 347.52 40.6302 348.22 40.1402C349.81 39.0102 351.9 38.7202 353.81 39.3602C357.1 40.4702 359 44.0302 358.04 47.2802C357.47 49.2202 355.83 51.6602 351.22 52.2402C351.15 52.2502 351.08 52.2602 351.02 52.2602Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M369.77 185.38H355.03C354.17 185.38 353.48 184.68 353.48 183.83C353.48 182.97 354.17 182.28 355.03 182.28H369.77C370.63 182.28 371.32 182.98 371.32 183.83C371.33 184.69 370.63 185.38 369.77 185.38Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M309.57 143.44C309.28 143.44 308.98 143.36 308.73 143.19L299.76 137.42C299.04 136.96 298.83 136 299.29 135.28C299.75 134.56 300.71 134.35 301.43 134.81L309.84 140.21L347.87 130.51L357.26 97.14C357.49 96.32 358.35 95.84 359.17 96.07C360 96.3 360.47 97.16 360.24 97.98L350.6 132.21C350.45 132.74 350.03 133.16 349.49 133.29L309.94 143.38C309.83 143.42 309.7 143.44 309.57 143.44Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M293.62 149.47C293.01 149.47 292.43 149.11 292.18 148.51C291.86 147.72 292.24 146.81 293.03 146.49L300.34 143.5C301.13 143.18 302.04 143.56 302.36 144.35C302.69 145.14 302.3 146.05 301.51 146.37L294.2 149.36C294.01 149.43 293.81 149.47 293.62 149.47Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M314.02 157.16C313.37 157.16 312.76 156.75 312.55 156.1L309.89 148.12C309.62 147.31 310.06 146.43 310.87 146.16C311.69 145.89 312.56 146.33 312.83 147.14L315.49 155.12C315.76 155.93 315.32 156.81 314.51 157.08C314.35 157.14 314.18 157.16 314.02 157.16Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M334.98 63.53C332.78 63.53 331.16 63.02 331.03 62.98C330.21 62.72 329.77 61.84 330.03 61.03C330.29 60.22 331.16 59.76 331.98 60.03C332.01 60.04 336.05 61.27 339.36 59.34C340.1 58.91 341.05 59.16 341.48 59.9C341.91 60.64 341.66 61.59 340.92 62.02C338.9 63.2 336.75 63.53 334.98 63.53Z" fill="black"/>

<path d="M312.36 130.31C311.51 130.31 310.82 129.59 310.81 128.74L310.48 98.6802C310.47 97.8202 311.16 96.9602 312.02 96.9602C312.02 96.9602 312.03 96.9602 312.04 96.9602C312.89 96.9602 313.58 97.7802 313.59 98.6302L313.92 128.65C313.93 129.51 313.24 130.32 312.39 130.32C312.37 130.31 312.36 130.31 312.36 130.31Z" fill="black"/>
</g>

</svg>
```